# Error when use linq .any() in checkboxfor()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

**Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.**

I had search through google, and cant see to find better way to solve this, I want to do a check if the data exist in table, then set to true, else set to false, is there anywhere to make it work? If there is no way to use linq to make it work,  what I can think of is to use jquery ajax to populate the table

```
<tbody>
       @foreach (var item in (ViewData["menu"] as IEnumerable<overview>))
       {
           <tr>
           <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(model=>model.AccessRights.Where(m=> m.mcd ==item.mcd && m.ise=="Y").Any())
           </tr>
       }
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `overview` ViewModel to include for example:

```
public bool AccessRightsExist {get;set;}
```

then in your controller you set it:

```
overviewModel.AccessRightsExist = dbContext.AccessRights.Where(m=> m.ise=="Y").Any();
```

and last, your view would then be:

```
<td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(model=>item.AccessRightsExist)</td>
```

If you don't have a ViewModel, add one to your solution.

Comment: It is workable? because I need to compare it with the  @foreach (var item in (ViewData["menu"] as IEnumerable<overview>))

Comment: Change the overview model to include the boolean you need

Comment: I learned something today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12674572/proper-usage-of-net-mvc-html-checkboxfor - +1 for the nice answer.

Comment: @PostureOfLearning, hmmm, ok, your word give me some idea, let me try to play around with my overview class and see if it is workable

Comment: @retailcoder, yeah, I did check every post in SO for the problem