# MVC 5 Razor view not binding bool to input

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a razor view (Framework 4.5, MVC 5) and an html input type=checkbox with the value equal to a model boolean value but instead of true or false it binds "value".

This is my code:

```
for (int index = 0; index < Model.Item1.Locations.Length; index++)
        {
            WSTupleOfInt32StringStringBoolean location = Model.Item1.Locations[index];
                <div class="editor-field">
                    <input id="@string.Format("presentation.ServiceInfoes[{1}].Locations[{0}].Key", index, Model.Item2)" type="checkbox" value="@location.ThirdValue" name="@string.Format("presentation.ServiceInfoes[{1}].Locations[{0}].ThirdValue", index, Model.Item2)" />
                </div>
                <div class="editor-label">
                    <label for="@string.Format("presentation.ServiceInfoes[{1}].Locations[{0}].Key", index, Model.Item2)">@location.FirstValue</label>
                    @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(location.SecondValue))
                    {
                        <a href="@string.Format("//maps.google.com/?q={0}", location.SecondValue)" target="_blank"><img alt="@location.SecondValue" src="@string.Format("//maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center={0}&markers=color:blue|{0}&zoom=15&size=64x64&sensor=false", location.SecondValue)" /></a>
                    }
                </div><br />
        }
```

The `location.ThirdValue` is the boolean property, debuging the property it's fine.. but in the HTML i get `value="value"` and not `value="false"`.

What's happening?

Answer (score 9):

See this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12674572/proper-usage-of-net-mvc-html-checkboxfor)

Basically you want to use `HTML.CheckBoxFor(model => model.booleanProperty)`

Comment: On my model I had public bool NewContact { get; '*internal'* set; } which made the "NewContact" always false even with CheckboxFor. Removing internal and this works. Upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

Do this

```
<input id="@string.Format("presentation.ServiceInfoes[{1}].Locations[{0}].Key", index, Model.Item2)" type="checkbox" @(location.ThirdValue ? "checked" : "") name="@string.Format("presentation.ServiceInfoes[{1}].Locations[{0}].ThirdValue", index, Model.Item2)" />
```

The value is not setting checkbox to be checked or not, value has different function. For example if you set value to 'test' and check the checkbox, when you submit the form, you will see that instead of true value of submitted variable will be 'test';

you can do pretty cool stuff with it. For example you have 3 checkboxes on your form. all of them have the same name, but different values. when you submit the form, the result you get will be comma-separated string with values of checked checkboxes;