# Bool from viewmodel is not binding in MVC action on a post

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, formcollection

I have a view model that has `TestStr` and `TestBool` as properties. If I submit the form, only the `TestStr` value is getting set to the bound view model, but not the `TestBool`. The value in the form collection for `TestBool` is set to `"on"`, is that the issue? Should it be set as `true` for it to be marked as true?

My c# view model:

```
public class MyViewModel { 
  public bool TestStr { get; set; }
  public bool TestBool { get; set; }
}
```

My razor view, inside the form:

```
<input name="TestStr" value="this is getting set in my MVC action" />
<input name="TestBool" checked=checked /> // this always gets set to false, even tho it's checked
```

My MVC action:

```
public ActionResult(MyViewModel vm) {
  // vm.TestBool is always false
}
```

I notice that if I use the `@Html.CheckBoxFor(...)` it does correctly bind it in my MVC action. Is it possible to do this using the typed-out html? Only because I have some collections I'm working with, so I'm having to provide the input names for each.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Proper usage of .net MVC Html.CheckBoxFor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12674572/proper-usage-of-net-mvc-html-checkboxfor)

Answer (score 0):

Its because checkboxes don't post back if they are not checked. The HTML helper actually adds a hidden field for the unchecked version, then resolves the conflict (checked / not checked ) correctly.

If you want to preserve other fields, but don't want to display them, `Html.HiddenFor` can be used to preserve the values.

This post shows someone with the [same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12674572/128444)

Comment: But, checkboxes that _are_ checked are posted back, but with value as "on" and not "true".

Comment: That's by design. They always post back with on, its part of the HTML specification. The ModelBinder knows this, so it converts the 'on' to true for you.