# catching checkbox value in Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a checkbox in a partial view

```
<div>Full time:  @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.FullTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "txtIsFullTime" } })</div>
```

in the same partial view I have this Ajax code:

```
<script>
var urlAction = "@Url.Content("~/Treeview/_NewEmpThird")"; 
function AjaxGoodRedirect(urlAction) {           
    console.log(urlAction);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: urlAction,
        data: JSON.stringify({ FullTime: $("#txtIsFullTime").val() }),  //data: JSON.stringify({ ID: 1, Forename: "FName", Surname: "SName" }),
        datatype: "JSON",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (returndata) {
            if (returndata.ok)
                $("#detailView").load(returndata.newurl);
            else
                window.alert(returndata.message);
        }
    }

    );
}
```

But it is passing back a False value every time.

I used the same method for an @Html.EditorFor and had no problems - can anyone help point out where i have gone wrong?

thanks :)

edit

Think the issue was with the new html attributes =  new.. removed that (and corrected the typo)

div>Full time:  @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.FullTime,  new { id = "txtFullTime" })

then used

data: JSON.stringify({ ID: $("#txtFullTime").is(':checked') ? 1 : 0 })

and no returns 1 or 0.

Comment: Its `txtIsFullTime` in your HTML and not `textIsFullTime` as in your ajax.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use in a form mapper that I've built:

```
switch (field.prop('type')) {
    case 'checkbox':
        newVal = this.checked;
        break;
    default:
        newVal = field.val();
        break;
}
```

So you probably have to change `$("#txtIsFullTime").val()` to `$("#txtIsFullTime").get(0).checked` or `$("#txtIsFullTime").is(':checked')`

**UPDATE**

I believe the value `1` or `0` is because an `Html.CheckBoxFor()` generates 2 inputs. One for the value (0|1), one for the state (true|false). This is a requirement on MVC level.

[More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12674572/proper-usage-of-net-mvc-html-checkboxfor)

Comment: If the downvote is only based on the ID mismatch, correct the ID and then you still have an issue using `.val()` ... just saying ...

Comment: Hi, I didn't downgrade this.  Yep you are right with the typo, i had previously corrected that and still didn't work.

Comment: .checked kicks off a syntax error and the second one doesn't seem to capture it either as still returning false.  same as .prop('checked')

Answer (score 0):

My guess:

```
id = "txtIsFullTime"
$("#textIsFullTime")
```

ID mismatch