# Which checkbox is checked(controller) and results to list

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to asp.net mvc. I am making an online video store application.

I have this view:

[image]

where users can choose which videos their gonna rent. The code for the view:

```
@model IEnumerable<VideoRentalSystem.Models.VideoMaintenance>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Video Rentals</h2>
<h5 style="color:red">Only available videos is shown.</h5>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Genre)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Rating)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Quantity)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UnitsAvailable)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RentalPrice)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Genre)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Rating)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Quantity)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UnitsAvailable)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RentalPrice)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.CheckBox("Rent?", new { id= item.VideoMaintenanceID})
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>

<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Rent Selected Videos" />
```

Like you can see at the bottom of the code where I add the checkbox I (hopefully) give the checkbox an ID equal to the video info left of the textbox. What I want to know is how will I, if the user clicks the 'Rent Selected Videos' button, get all the selected videos and add it to a list, inside the controller-hope this makes sense?

My current controller:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using VideoRentalSystem.DAL;

namespace VideoRentalSystem.Controllers
{
    public class VideoRentalsController : Controller
    {
        private VideoRentalContext db = new VideoRentalContext();

        // GET: VideoRentals
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var available = from a in db.VideosMaintenance
                            select a;

            available = available.Where(av => av.UnitsAvailable != 0);

            return View(available);
        }
    }
}
```

My Model for the VideoMaintenance:

```
//Primary Key
        public int VideoMaintenanceID { get; set; }

        [StringLength(60, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "A maximum of 60 and a minimum of 3 characters is allowed")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
        public string Title { get; set; }


        [RegularExpression(@"^[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z''-'\s]*$", ErrorMessage = "Only letters is allowed")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
        [StringLength(140, ErrorMessage = "A maximum of 140 characters is allowed")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [RegularExpression(@"^[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z''-'\s]*$", ErrorMessage = "Only letters is allowed")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
        [StringLength(30, ErrorMessage = "A maximum of 30 characters is allowed")]
        public string Genre { get; set; }

        [StringLength(15, ErrorMessage = "A maximum of 15 characters is allowed")]
        public string Rating { get; set; }

        [RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]+$", ErrorMessage = "Only numbers is allowed")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
        public int Quantity { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Units Available")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]+$", ErrorMessage = "Only numbers is allowed")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
        public int UnitsAvailable { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Rental Price")]
        [Range(1, 100, ErrorMessage = "Range between 1,100")]
        [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
        public decimal RentalPrice { get; set; }

        //Foreign Key
        public virtual ICollection<CustomerMaintenance> CustomersMaintenance { get; set; }
    }
```

...and my model for CustomerMaintenance:

```
//Primary Key
        [Display(Name = "Identification Number")]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]+$", ErrorMessage = "Only numbers is allowed")]
        public string CustomerMaintenanceID { get; set; }

        [StringLength(30, ErrorMessage = "A maximum of 30 characters is allowed")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z''-'\s]*$", ErrorMessage = "Only letters is allowed")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [StringLength(60, ErrorMessage = "A maximum of 60 characters is allowed")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z''-'\s]*$", ErrorMessage = "Only letters it allowed")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
        public string Surname { get; set; }

        [StringLength(250, ErrorMessage = "A maximum of 250 characters is allowed")]
        //[RegularExpression(@"^[A-Z]+[0-9]+[a-zA-Z''-'\s]*$")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
        [Display(Name = "Physical Address")]
        public string Address { get; set; }

        [StringLength(10, ErrorMessage = "A maximum of 10 characters is allowed")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]+$", ErrorMessage = "Only numbers allowed")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
        [Display(Name = "Phone Number")]
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

        //Foreign Key
        public virtual VideoMaintenance VideosMaintenance { get; set; }
```

My DbContext:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using VideoRentalSystem.Models;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;

namespace VideoRentalSystem.DAL
{
    public class VideoRentalContext : DbContext
    {
        //Passes name of the connnection string to the constructor
        public VideoRentalContext() : base("VideoRentalContext")
        {

        }

        public DbSet<CustomerMaintenance> CustomersMaintenance { get; set; }
        public DbSet<VideoMaintenance> VideosMaintenance { get; set; }

        //Override entity naming convention- disable pluralisation 
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingEntitySetNameConvention>();
        }
    }
}
```

I apologize for this long question! Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29542107/pass-list-of-checkboxes-into-view-and-pull-out-ienumerable/29554416#29554416) for an example of using checkboxes in a collection

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a great use case to make use of **Editor Templates**.

Create a view model like this for your view.

```
public class RentVideoVM
{       
    public List<VideoSelection> Videos { set; get; } 
    //Add other properties needed for your view.
}

public class VideoSelection
{
    public int VideoId { set; get; }
    public string Name { set; get; }   

    public bool IsSelected { set; get; }
   //Add other properties needed for your view.
}
```

The `IsSelected` property of `VideoSelection` class is used to store users selection on the check box from the UI.

Now in your GET action method, create an instance of the `RentVideoVM` viewmodel, Load the Videos collection and send it to the view,

```
public ActionResult Register()
{
    var vm = new RentVideoVM();
    vm.Videos = db.Videos.Select(s => new VideoSelection
    {
        VideoId = s.VideoId,
        Name = s.VideoName
    }).ToList();
    return View(vm);
}
```

*Change it `db.YourWhateverDBSet` instead of `db.Videos`*

Now we need to create an editor template. Go to `Views` folder and go inside the folder for your current controller and create a sub folder called "EditorTemplates". Add a new view there with the name `VideoSelection.cshtml` and have the below code there.

```
@model YourNamespace.VideoSelection
<div>
    @Model.Name

    @Html.CheckBoxFor(d=>d.IsSelected)

    @Html.HiddenFor(s => s.VideoId)
</div>
```

You may change the html markup however you want. Make it fancy !

[image]

Now in your main view, which is bound to our `RentVideoVM` view model , call the `Html.EditorFor` helper method to render the Videos with checkboxes.

```
@model YourNamespace.RentVideoVM
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorFor(s=>s.Videos)
    <input type="submit"/>
}
```

And your `HttpPost` action to handle the form posting would be

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(RentVideoVM model)
{
   //check model.Videos collection
   // to do : Save and redirect
   // If something wrong happened, reload Videos collection 
    return View(model);
}
```

When user posts the form, you can inspect the `Videos` collection of the posted model. `IsSelected` property will be true for those videos which user checked.

[image]

Comment: Sure will try this! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

you may want to build a view model

```
public class YourDBContext
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class YourDBContextView
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

and use @using (Html.BeginForm()) on the view

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(IEnumerable<YourDBContextView> obj)
{
    //You can get your checkbox here
    foreach(YourDBContextView view in obj)
    {
        bool test = view.IsSelected;
    }
}
```