# Calling httppost actionresult from inside a view using a button

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view, actionresult

I have a project to make an online shop between users (post a product, buy, etc.) using a database. In this project I have a view called "ShoppingCart":

```
@model IEnumerable<MyFirstProject.Models.Product>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ShoppingCart";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Your Shopping Cart</h2>



@if (Model == null)
{
    <div style="float:left">Your cart is empty.</div>
    <div>
        Total payment: 0
    </div>
}
else
{
    decimal tPrice = 0;
    <div>
    <table style="float:left">
        @foreach (var product in Model)
        {
            tPrice = tPrice + product.Price;
            { Html.RenderPartial("ProductLine", product);}
        }
    </table>
        </div>
    <div>
        Total payment: @tPrice
    </div>
}
```

It receives a list of products which the user decided to buy and displays them (not the important part). I need to add a button which will send the list to an action result in the "ShoppingController":

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ShoppingCart(List<Product> bought)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                foreach (var listP in bought.ToList())
                {
                    foreach (var databaseP in db.Products.ToList())
                    {
                        if (listP.ProductID == databaseP.ProductID)
                        {
                            databaseP.State = 1;
                            db.SaveChanges();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            else
            {
                return View(bought);
            }
        }
```

"State" indicates if the product was bought or not (0=not bought, 1=bought), db is the database

Comment: You don't. (you would need to include a form control for every property of every product in you view). If this is a confirmation page, then you just post a ID value and then retrieve the collection of products the user has already selected and retrieve it from the repository you previously stored it (I assume you used `Session`?)

Answer (score 0):

If you wan't to post any data from a view to an action method, you should keep that data in form elements and keep that in a form.  Since you want to post a collection of items, You may use **Editor Templates**.

Let's start by creating a view model.

```
public class ShoppingCartViewModel
{
    public decimal TotalPrice { set; get; }
    public List<Product> CartItems { set; get; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public string Name { set; get; }
}
```

Now in your GET action, you will create an object of the `ShoppingCartViewModel`, load the `CartItems` property and send to the view.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var cart = new ShoppingCartViewModel
    {
        CartItems = new List<Product>
        {
            new Product   { Id = 1, Name = "Iphone" },
            new Product   { Id = 3, Name = "MacBookPro" }
        },
        TotalPrice = 3234.95
    };
    return View(cart);
}
```

Now i will create an EditorTemplate. To do that, Go to your `~/Views/YourControllerName` folder, and Create a directory called `EditorTemplates` and add a view with name `Product.cshtml`

*The name of the file should match with the name of the type.*

[image]

Open this new view and add the below code.

```
@model YourNamespace.Product
<div>
    <h4>@Model.Name</h4>
    @Html.HiddenFor(s=>s.Id)
</div>
```

You can keep the display however you want. But the important thing is, We need to keep a form field for the productId. We are keeping that in a hidden field here.

Now let's go back to our main view. We need to make this view strongly typed to our `ShoppingCartViewModel`. We will use the `EditorFor` html helper method in this view to call our editor template

```
@model ReplaceYourNamespaceHere.ShoppingCartViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{       
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.CartItems)
    <p>Total : @Model.TotalPrice</p>
    <input type="submit" />
}
```

And in your HttpPost action method, We will have a paramer of type `ShoppingCartViewModel`. When the form is submitted, MVC Model binder will map the posted form values to an object of `ShoppingCartViewModel`.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(ShoppingCartViewModel model)
{
    foreach (var item in model.CartItems)
    {
        var productId = item.Id;
        // to do  : Use productId and do something
    }
    return RedirectToAction("OrderSucessful");
}
```

You can iterate through the `CartItems` collection and get the Id of the Products and do whatever you want.

[image]

If you wan't to allow the user to edit the items (using a check box) in this page, Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33659157/which-checkbox-is-checkedcontroller-and-results-to-list/33660035#33660035). It is basically same, but you add a boolean property to Product class and use that for rendering a checkbox.