# Checked CheckBox not showing up in ActionResult FormsCollection MVC 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkbox, collections, httprequest, form-submit

My code has undergone an incredible change in order to make mutlitple checkboxes work. I did away with the formsCollection I was trying to use to loop through checked checkboxes on the View. I am using a lot of loops inside of loops both in Controller and in View and I don't care anymore about "separation of concerns" or anything modern about MVC. In MS Access you can lump a whole bunch of functions into one line which makes it unreadable but works. I always spread out the logic in order to understand it and step through it. I am probably using a sophomoric approach to this new modern world of MVC 6 but I don't care. I can move on out of the Roles crap into actually doing something with CRUD. I also don't want to piss  Stephen Muecke off at all since most of my MVC knowledge is a compilation of his attention to my questions. After Googling it with Bing I found **[this link about checkboxes](http://gunaatita.com/blog/Send-multiple-checkbox-values-from-view-to-controller-in-MVC/10)** that was very simple and helpful. And most of my view was already set up. My time was spent on displaying the user's roles that were already checked. So now, I have a View and an Edit form that allows adding or removing Roles for selected user via checkboxes. Not pretty but very tasty IMHO. ("MVC6" is the name of my project, not a built in name). I did not have to use Owin dependencies. Only dependentcy I had to add was to enable session so I could send TempData["Status"] message. Everything else is right out of the "box".

**View:**

```
    @using MVC6.Models
    @using Microsoft.AspNet.Http
    @model Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUser

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Edit User";

        var roles = new MVC6Context().Roles.ToList();
        var usersroles = new MVC6Context().UserRoles.ToList();



    }
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Administration", "Index", "Admin")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Users", "Index", "UserManagement")</li>
        <li>Edit User</li>
    </ol>

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary()

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Email)
        <h3>Username:</h3>
        <div class="form-control">
            @Model.Email
        </div>

        <h3>Roles:</h3>

        if (roles.Any())
        {
            <div >
                @foreach (var role in roles)
                {
                    bool isinrole = false;

                    @foreach (var ur in usersroles)
                    {
                      @if (Model.Id == ur.UserId) //usersroles returns all roles for all users
                     {
                        @if(ur.RoleId == role.Id)
                        {
                            isinrole = true;
                        }
                      }
                    }

                    @if (isinrole)
                    {
                        <input type="checkbox" name="checkRoles" value="@role.Name" checked />
                        @Html.Label(role.Name)
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        <input type="checkbox" name="checkRoles" value="@role.Name"/>
                        @Html.Label(role.Name)


                    }

                    <br/>
                }
            </div>
            <br />
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save</button> <span style="color:red;">@if (@TempData["Status"] != null){@TempData["Status"]}</span>
        }
        else
        {
            <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
                No roles available
            </div>
        }
        <br />
```

**Controller**

```
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Edit(string userId)
        {
            return View(context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == userId));
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(string[] checkRoles, string userID)
        {

            var UserManager = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
            var RoleManager = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
            var allRoles = RoleManager.Roles.ToList();
            var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(userID);           
            var usersRoles = await UserManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

            //LOOP THROUGH ROLES
            foreach (var item in allRoles)
            {
                bool wasChecked = false;
                //ALL CHECKBOXES THAT WERE CHECKED
                foreach (var roleChecked in checkRoles)
                {
                    if (item.Name == roleChecked)
                    {
                        wasChecked = true;
                    }
                }

                //ALL CHECKBOXES THAT WERE NOT CHECKED
                if (wasChecked == false)
                {
                    //IF USER HAS ROLE, REMOVE IT
                    if (await UserManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, item.Name))
                    {
                        await UserManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync(user, item.Name);
                    }
                }
                else     //IF CHECK BOX CHECKED THEN ADD ROLE TO USER
                {
                    await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, item.Name);
                }

            }

            TempData["Status"] = "Roles are updated as of <b>" + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + "</b>";

            return View(user);

        }
```

What might help another newbie like me is that the AspNetUserRoles table has 2 columns, UserId and RuleId. This is a "many-to-many" relationship. In my code above once I get all the info about the user I want to edit, and get all the user's roles from this many-to-many, then I can iterate through it to add or delete a row. Kinda same thing for the View. I know this stuff could be refactored but it is doing business as we talk. I would gladly give accepted answer to someone who even slightly refactors this (but doesn't turn it into mad scientist gobbly gook, all due respect).

Comment: Do not use `FormCollection` Use a view model and strongly bind to your model - for example [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29542107/pass-list-of-checkboxes-into-view-and-pull-out-ienumerable/29554416#29554416)

Comment: Oh man. I was hoping for a reason why nothing was in the FormsCollection hack I was doing. The MVC 5 code I am upgrading to MVC 6 does see the forms collection and does loop through and add the role(s). I was just trying to add one role from the forms collection. So. . . I've bookmarked your example and when I have cleared my mind and taken a ton of B-Complex  I will assimilate it. thank you

Comment: Ok, rebuilding from scratch using your way. I made the ViewModel and in the Edit ActionResult I have the user and the roles but I don't know how to map properties to the ViewModel as per your commented text:
  // Get you User based on the ID and map properties to the ViewModel
  // including populating the Roles and setting their IsSelect property
  // based on existing roles

Comment: In that example, `IEnumerable<string> selectedRoles = model.Roles.Where(r => r.IsSelected).Select(r => r.Name);`  would give you the names of selected roles. So in your case you would want something like `foreach(string role in selectedRoles) { RoleAddToUser(user.Id, role); }`

Comment: Thanks for the attention yet I haven't even figured out how to populate the ViewModel with User and Roles AND  . .. .include which ones are selected:

Comment: `model.Roles = roles.Select(r => new RoleVM{ ID = r.ID, Name = r.Name });` will add all available roles. Then if you editing and existing user, you can loop through the users roles and find the corresponding RoleVM and set the `IsSelected` property to true.

Comment: I'm going to keep trying but i have little faith in my abilities when it comes to this problem of multiple checkboxes. Where, might I ask, do I put the last line? model.Roles roles.Select(R=> new RoleVM{ID=r.ID, Name=r.Name});