# How to add Create and Edit View to Model with IEnuernation<T> properties?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, entity-framework-6, ef-model-first

let's say I use Entity Framework 6 and have the following two tables in a model-first approach:

[image]

This creates following code:

[image]

[image]

My question is now, how do I use the IEnumeration properties in a Create View? In a Details or Delete View, I just iterate through them using Html.DisplayFor helper, but I don't know what I could use to achieve the comparable for Create and Edit Views. Something like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MappedEmployees, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <!--Something like checkbox list with Name property of each collection property item-->
    </div>
</div>
```

So I would end up with something like:

[image]

Comment: This is more of an MVC razor question than EF.

Comment: Are you wanting to display all employees and then use a checkbox to select the ones associated with Account?

Comment: yes, that is what I am trying to achieve...

Comment: Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29542107/pass-list-of-checkboxes-into-view-and-pull-out-ienumerable/29554416#29554416) for an example (instead or User and Roles, it would be Account and Employees)

Answer (score 0):

There's a few good blog posts on this subject, they should be useful for you in this area:

[haacked.com blog posting](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/)

[Hanselman.com blog posting](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx)

I've not tested the below, but something like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MappedEmployees, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">

@for(int i = 0; i < model.MappedEmployees.Count; i ++)
{
Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.MappedEmployees[i],  new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
}

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it seems that I need a bool value for the expression parameter of the CheckBoxFor constructor. I don't know however how to get it working so that it can add/remove items from my ICollection property.