# Binding Model.ID to Checkbox list and post Model.X, Model.Y, etc. properties to Controller

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, checkbox, checkboxlist

In an `MVC` application I joined multiple tables and returned it from `Controller` to `View` as shown below:

```
| EmployeeID | ControlID | DoorAddress | DoorID | DoorName |
------------------------------------------------------------
|  921       |     1     |      1      |  101   | Door 1   |
|  921       |     1     |      2      |  102   | Door 2   |
|  921       |     1     |      3      |  103   | Door 3   |
|  921       |     1     |      4      |  104   | Door 4   |
------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    // Create and execute raw SQL query.
    string query = "SELECT a.EmployeeID, a.ControlID, a.DoorAddress, t.DoorID, t.DoorName FROM TEmpAccess AS a " +
                   "INNER JOIN TDoor AS t ON a.ControlID = t.ControlID and a.DoorAddress = t.DoorAddress where EmployeeID = " + id.ToString();
    IEnumerable<EmpAccessViewModel> data = db.Database.SqlQuery<EmpAccessViewModel>(query);

    return View(data.ToList());
}
```

I want to bind `DoorName` values (Door 1, Door 2, Door 3, Door 4) to a `checkbox list` and let the user to select them. After that, I want to pass corresponding `EmployeeID`, `ControlID`, `DoorAddress`, `DoorID` values of the the selected door to the `Controller`. For example if the user selects Door 1 and Door 3, then I will pass these values below to the `Controller`:

```
| EmployeeID | ControlID | DoorAddress | DoorID |
-------------------------------------------------
|  921       |     1     |      1      |  101   | 
|  921       |     1     |      3      |  103   | 
-------------------------------------------------
```

By using `razor` syntax or `javascript` in the view, how can I do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a view model including a `bool IsSelected` property so you can bind it to a checkbox. Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29542107/pass-list-of-checkboxes-into-view-and-pull-out-ienumerable/29554416#29554416) for an example

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks, but the given answers does not have a checkbox list. Could you please give an example regarding to my question (I returned the given list above by using sql query) having checkbox list?

Comment: Of course it does! Study it - each item in the collection has a checkbox associated with it. When the form is submitted you can query the returned collection and get the selected items using `.Where(m => m.IsSelected)`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks a lot. I post the selected IDs, but cannot bind the checkboxes according to the values they have (for example it would be enough for me to bind only the checkboxes that have ID value). Is it possible?

Comment: Sorry, but you have not shown the new code you are now trying so impossible to understand. Either append the new code to this question or ask a new question explaining what problems your having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a checkbox at the beginning of the Table in the view which is to be passed to the controller and each row is uniquely identified by the `DoorID` you could try something like this.

in View

```
<table>
@foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" value="@item.DoorID" name="doorid" /></td>
                <td>@item.EmployeeID</td>
                <td>@item.ControlID</td>
                <td>@item.DoorName</td>
            </tr>
        }
</table>
```

In controller

```
public void ControllerName(int[] doorid)
{
        foreach(var item in doorid)

          //do something
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer... I managed to post the selected IDs, but I cannot bind the checkbox although I used @Stephen's isSelected property in the model. Any idea?

Comment: On the other hand I tried, but cannot vote up as I have not enough reputation :(