# How Post the list of items from PartialView to controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

This is quite simple situation actually, but I can't get how to make this work. So, there is list of checkboxes rendered in **PartialView**. Data passed from parent **ViewModel** to child **ViewModel** in PartialView. All these wrapped by form, unfortunately I can't get the data from **PartialView**.
Parent ViewModel:

```
public class UserProgramsViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Введите название")]
        [DisplayName("Название")]
        public string ProgramName { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Пользователь")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Пользователь")]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Дни Программы")]
        public ICollection<ProgramDaysDTO> ProgramDays { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<DaysViewModel> Days { get;  set;} //Passed to Partial
    }
```

Child ViewModel:

```
public class DaysViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string DayName { get; set; }
    }
```

Parent View:

```
@Html.Partial("Days", Model.Days)
```

PartialView (here we are using attribute name 'Days' to bind it to Parent model)

```
@model IEnumerable<BBN.Admin.ViewModels.DaysViewModel>
<ul class="list-group col-lg-2">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" name="Days" value="@item.Id" /> @item.DayName</li>
    }
</ul>
```

Controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [RBAC]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Create(UserProgramsViewModel model)
        {
            var groups = await _us.GetAll();
            ViewBag.Users = groups.Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = x.Login,
                Value = x.Id.ToString()
            });
            var dto = new UserProgramsDTO
            {
                ProgramName = model.ProgramName,
                UserId = model.UserId,
                Days = model.Days
            };
            var result = await _ps.Create(dto);
            if (result.IsSuccess == (BLL.Utilities.Enums.IsSuccess)Enums.IsSuccess.Success) return RedirectToAction("Index");
            else return View("Create");
        }
```

Comment: `Days` is a complex object and you cannot bind a checkbox to a complex object. Nor can you use a `foreach` loop to generate form controls for a collection. You need a view model and a `for` loop similar to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29542107/pass-list-of-checkboxes-into-view-and-pull-out-ienumerable/29554416#29554416)

Comment: Guys, thanks for ideas, let me try few solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `FormCollection`. Assign `item.DayName` to input's name attribute:

**PartialView(fragment):**

```
<li class="list-group-item">
      <input type="checkbox" name="@(item.DayName)Days" @if (item.Id > 0) { <text>checked</text> } /> @item.DayName
</li>
```

Then process `FormCollection` parameter and fill model's `Days` property with it's help:

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
[RBAC]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(UserProgramsViewModel model, FormCollection formCollection)
{
    model.Days = new List<DaysViewModel>();
    foreach(var key in formCollection.AllKeys.Where(x => x.Contains("Days")))
        model.Days.Add(new DaysViewModel { Id = formCollection[key] == "on" ? 1 : 0, DayName = key.Replace("Days", "")} );

     //other stuff...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you set values for "Days" in your parent view from controller?
like Suppose your parent view name is "Parent" then you should write like this,

```
public ActionResult Parent()
{
     UserProgramsViewModel loUser = new UserProgramsViewModel(); 
       //Assign Your values here

     View(loUser); 
}
```

So may be you will not get Null value here.