# How can we know which @HTML.CheckBox() are checked in the View from the Controller in MVC5

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I spent many days trying to pass the information from the View to the Controller
using `@Html.CheckBox()`

I have a textarea and a loop of checkboxes (we don't know how many).
I can manage the textarea but not the checkboxes.

The View:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("ProviderConfigurationTool", "Admin"))
    {
        <div>
            <strong>Custom Rule </strong>
            @Html.TextArea("CustomRule", new { rows = 12, columns = 30 })
            <br />
        </div>
        foreach (var item in ViewBag.farmlist)
        {
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="border-bottom: solid 1px #EBEFF6">
                                <p>@item</p>
                                @Html.CheckBox("@item");
                                <!-- <input id="@item" name="@item" type="checkbox" onclick="addingFarms('@item')" class="farms" /> -->
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
          }

            <input type="submit" value="Submit and close" onclick="refreshParent();self.close()" />

    }
    @{Html.EndForm();}
```

As you can I tried also with the normal html code using "type=checkbox"

The Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(string CustomRule, FormCollection collection)
    {

            string results = collection["Blanks"]; // it does not work
            newRule.Key = CustomRule; // it works
    }
```

The other idea was using javascript and trying to create a List to pass to the controller like that

View:
 `input id="@item" name="@item" type="checkbox" onclick="getFarms('@item')" class="farms"`

```
function getFarms() {
    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        inputs[i].checked = true;
        //Here I am blocked because I don't know how to pass a new list to the controller
    }
```

If somebody already got this problem or have an idea, please help me!

Comment: Your creating checkboxes which have `name` attributes that have no relationship at all to your model. Suggest to study the code in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29542107/pass-list-of-checkboxes-into-view-and-pull-out-ienumerable/29554416#29554416)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ajax for this.
In the `.cshtml` page:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='ch' value='@item'>
```

In JQuery:

```
var it=$('ch:checked').serialize();  $.ajax('yourcontoroller/youractionname',it)
```

In your Controller:

```
public ActionResult Create(string customRule, string[] ch) 
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help, like I said above it's very important to have the same variable name in the controller and the view

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, HTML forms are used to collect user input. For check-boxes, the value property only has meaning when submitting a form. If a check-box is in checked state when the form is submitted, the name of the check-box is sent along with the value of the value property (if the check box is not checked, no information is sent). So, if you assign a name to check-boxes, your Controller receives and array
of checked values by the name. So, the declaration of the check-boxes should something like this.

```
<input name="checkboxes" type="checkbox" value="@item" />
```

and your Controller

```
public ActionResult Create(string customRule, string[] checkboxes) 
{
    ...
}
```

The `checkboxes` contains all values which are checked.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works fine, I understand that the point is to have the same variable name "checkboxes" in the input and in the controller