# How can I create a list of checkboxes that tie back to my model? (MVC5)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can I create a list of checkboxes that tie back to my model?
I'm not understanding how I can get the list of checkboxes back when I post to the controller.

I have a view model:

```
public class Widget
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string WidgetName { get; set; }
    public string WidgetDescription { get; set; }

    public List<MyPart> Parts { get; set; }
}

public class MyPart
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string PartName { get; set; }
    public string PartDescription { get; set; }
}
```

I am displaying the Widget (ID, Name, Description) in my cshtml page.

I created a partial page to display the list of parts.

```
@model IEnumerable<MySite.DataAccess.MyPart>

    @foreach (var itm in Model)
    {
        <li style="list-style-type:none">              
            @(Html.Kendo().CheckBox().Name("parts").Label(@itm.PartDescription).HtmlAttributes(new { @id = @itm.ID.ToString() }))
        </li>
    }
```

Called in my main cshtml as:

```
@Html.Partial("_MyPartial", @Model.Parts)
```

EDIT:
I have also tried:

```
@model IEnumerable<MySite.DataAccess.MyPart>

    @foreach (var itm in Model)
    {
        <li style="list-style-type:none">            
            @(Html.CheckBoxFor(x => @itm.IsSelected, new { id = @itm.ID.ToString() }))
            @(Html.HiddenFor(x => @itm.ID))
            @(Html.DisplayFor(x => @itm.PartDescription ))            
        </li>
    }
```

Of course adding a IsSelected property to my MyPart class.

On the post I'm still not seeing the Parts collection (Parts = null)

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: When it posts to the controller the Parts = null.

Comment: Refer also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29542107/pass-list-of-checkboxes-into-view-and-pull-out-ienumerable/29554416#29554416)