# how to map index using jquery to repair indexes when remove

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-entities

**Problem**

when remove any course from table list html his position in center or first it make problem

in index in database

**Details**

IF I have list of courses as following :

Delphi

Flash

Photoshop

IF I remove flash by JQUERY remove button then click save button

it delete flash and Photoshop

because there are wrong in delete courses by using remove function in jquery

if i remove php it is working without any problem because it is last item

**suggestion**

using map function when remove but how to do that

if there are any solution for that without using map no problem

i use model as following

```
public class Cusomemp2
    {
        public List<EmployeeCourse> empcourses { get; set; }

    }
}
```

i use for edit httppost

```
var result = db.Employees
             .Where(p => p.Id == custom.Id)
             .Include(c => c.EmployeeCourses)
             .FirstOrDefault();
        if (custom.empcourses.Any())
        {
            foreach (var ec in result.EmployeeCourses.ToList())//to remove existing EmployeeCourses
            {
                db.EmployeeCourses.Remove(ec);
                db.SaveChanges();

            }
        }

        result.EmployeeCourses = custom.empcourses;
     db.SaveChanges();
```

in model view my code as following by jquery

**actually i need to modify
code below using map function if there are any function do that never mind**

```
     $(function () {
           //add courses using drop down
            var index = 0;
            $("#CourseId").change(function () {

                var id = $(this).val();
                var txt = $("#CourseId option:selected").text();

               $("#tb").append("<tr><td><input type = 'hidden' name='empcourses[" + index + "].CourseId' value='" + id + "'/></td><td>" + txt + "</td><td><input type='button' value='remove' class='r'</td></tr>")

                index++;

            });
            $("#tb").on("click", ".r", function () {
              // remove function
                $(this).parent().parent().remove();

                $(this).parent().prev().prev().remove();
             });

// retrieve data in edit view using ajax
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Employee/getcoursesbyempid",
                data:{x:$("#hid").val()},
                success: function (res) {
                    $.each(res, function (i, e) {

                          $("#tb").append("<tr><td><input type = 'hidden' name='empcourses[" + index + "].CourseId' value='" + e.Id + "'/></td><td>" + e.CourseName + "</td><td><input type='button' value='remove' class='r'</td></tr>")

                        index++;
                    });
                }

            })
        });
```

see image below to understand what i need
[image]

Comment: Rather that trying to rename indexers so they are zero-based and consecutive, just include a hidden input for the indexer which allows you to post back non-consecutive indexers (refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29161481/post-a-form-array-without-successful/29161796#29161796) for an explanation (in you case it will be `<input type="hidden" name="empcourses.Index" value=...`

Comment: But your UI does not really make sense. Why not render a checklist box listing all courses and bind the checkbox to a (say) `bool IsSelected` property so you can just select/unselect courses in the view (no javascript required and you get strong typed binding). Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29542107/pass-list-of-checkboxes-into-view-and-pull-out-ienumerable/29554416#29554416) for an example

Comment: how to make hidden can you update my post if possible

Comment: You need to study the links I gave you, particularly the 2nd one

Comment: what you mean  2nd one

Comment: The link in my second comment

Comment: this is different case about my case

Comment: can you help me in that if possible

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123615/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-ahmed-salah).