# Using CheckBoxFor to hold data?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper, checkboxfor

I want to use `CheckBoxFor()` rather `<input type="checkbox"/>`
I used the input like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="selectedItems" value="@item.Name" id="@item.Id"/>
```

here I used the checkbox to hold some values if selected, and then passed them to the controller in a `string[]` parameter (it's contained within `foreach` loop)
but how I implement the `CheckBoxFor` to behave the same, as I know so far, we can only pass a boolean expression as the first parameter?

Comment: you have to use jquery for that, or use the bool property with checkbox and in controller only process the string array if bool comes as true, which means checkbox checked

Comment: `CheckBoxFor()` is for binding to `boolean` properties. If you want a checked list box, refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29542107/pass-list-of-checkboxes-into-view-and-pull-out-ienumerable/29554416#29554416) for an example

Comment: I'm wondering if there any advantage of using the HTML helpers instead of the raw HTML inputs other than validating inputs, because I don't need the checkbox to be validated?

Comment: One of main reasons is to get 2-way model binding