# How do I implement Radio button group using asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, view, asp.net-mvc-5, viewmodel

I have Course, Offered Course , Course Registration table ,Section Table in my project I want to implement Course Registration system of each user.[image] this is my database diagram of the  project.[image]
I want to implement this feature like this . I don't implement this features of

```
   class time . public class Course
{
    [Key]

    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Credit { get; set; }
    public DateTime RegDate { get; set; }

    public string PreCourse { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("DepartmentId")]
    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OfferedCourse> OfferedCourses { get; set; }

}
```

this is my course model,

```
   public class Department
   {
    [Key]
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}
```

this is my department model,

```
     public class OfferedCourse
{
    [Key]
    public int OfferedCourseId { get; set; }
    public int Capacity { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CourseId")]
    public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
    public string TeacherId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("TeacherId")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    public int SectionId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("SectionId")]
    public virtual Section Section { get; set; }
    public int SemesterId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("SemesterId")]
    public virtual Semester Semester { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CourseRegistration> CourseRegistrations { get; set; }

}
```

this is my offered course for each semester.

```
     public class Section
{
    [Key]
    public int SectionId { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }



}
```

this is my section model.In this project, I am using asp.net identity framework for manage user like teacher, student. But have tried many ways to
manage the radio button in Course Registration View . How Can I implement this feature because I have different type of data like section and course name how can I handle this

Comment: You image shows checkboxes, not radio buttons. Assuming you do want to select multiple courses as suggested by your model, refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29542107/pass-list-of-checkboxes-into-view-and-pull-out-ienumerable/29554416#29554416) for a typical example of the view models and view

Comment: yeah I need radio button..  how can I do this....I need a view model I think but how can I implement

Comment: Sorry, impossible to understand from what you have shown. Is "Bachelor of Science ...." your `Section.Title` property? Are the 3 items under it the `OfferedCourses` for that `Section` DO you only want to select one of those 3?

Comment: each aubject have many sections like A,B or C,d. I want to show in view like this : Algorithm and al section of algorir using radio button

Answer (score 0):

If you're using mvc razor, you can generate your RadioButtons with a foreach. something like this:

```
//HTML code here
@foreach (var offeredCourse in Model.OfferedCourses)
{       
    @Html.RadioButton(offeredCourse.OfferedCourseId.ToString(), offeredCourse.ID)          
}
//HTML code here
```

but I'm not sure which model you're using. Please paste your Course Registration View code to be more specific with this answer

Comment: but section is another table

Comment: each subject has many section....I need generate radio button for each section for individual  subject

Comment: I don't write any course registration  view model yet because I don't understand  what need to do. but course registration  view model have  these property  studentId, offeredcourseId.. because I can find the section using offeredCourseId.

Comment: @HoqueMDZahidul Can you copy and paste your view code? (cshtml file) to verify which model you're using and to see how you're trying to generate these radiobuttons

Answer (score -1):

I think its easy to use radio buttons group... 
See this link http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_radio

but for registration page you should use `if else` code in javascript to handle your request:

```
<script>
$('#register-btn').click(function () {
    var regType = 0;
    if ($('#radio1').is(":checked")) {
        regType = 1;
    }
    if ($('#radio2').is(":checked")) {
        regType = 2;
    }
    if ($('#radio3').is(":checked")) {
        regType = 3;
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Registration/reg_Ajax",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: '{type: "' + regType + '"}',
        dataType: "text",
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            alert("fail");
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
});
```

view:

`<form>
  <input type="radio" name="reg" value="male" id="radio1" checked> Male<br>
  <input type="radio" name="reg" value="female" id="radio2"> Female<br>
  <input type="radio" name="reg" value="other" id="radio3"> Other  <br>
  <input type="Button"  value="Register" id="register-btn">
</form>`

Comment: First I need the view how can i handle this ?