# Checkbox checked value lost if !ModelState.IsValid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5.2

My approach here may be entirely wrong, but I'm slowly learning MVC... I have a form whereby a user must select a number of (or no) modules, based on this model:

```
public class MyProductModule
{
    public string ModuleName { get; set; }
    public bool Checked { get; set; }
}

public class ProductRequest
{

    public ProductRequest()
    {
        Modules = LoadModules();
    }

    public static List<MyProductModule> LoadModules()
    {
        return new List<MyProductModule>()
        {
            new MyProductModule() { ModuleName = "Module One", Checked = false },
            new MyProductModule() { ModuleName = "Module Two", Checked = false },
            new MyProductModule() { ModuleName = "Module Three", Checked = false }
        };
    }

    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("MyProduct Modules")]
    public List<MyProductModule> Modules { get; set; }
}
```

A check box list is rendered to display each module:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Modules.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Modules[i].Checked)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Modules[i].ModuleName)
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Modules[i].Checked, Model.Modules[i].ModuleName)
}
```

Finally, the form is processed like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult ProcessRequest(ProductRequest qd)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View("Index", qd);
    }
    else
    {
        // check email domains
        List<string> badDomains = new List<string>();
        badDomains.Add("gmail");
        badDomains.Add("yahoo");
        badDomains.Add("hotmail");
        foreach (string s in badDomains)
        {
            if (qd.Email.Contains(string.Format("@{0}.", s)))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, string.Format("Please use your work email address.", s));
            }
        }

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View("Index", qd);
        }
        else
        {
            // process
        }
    }
}
```

Everything is working perfectly, unless for some reason my server-side validation fails, and the model is sent back (`return View("Index", qd);`).  At that point, the checkbox list mysteriously changes from this:

```
[x] Module One
[ ] Module Two
[ ] Module Three
```

...to this:

```
[ ] Module One
[ ] Module Two
[ ] Module Three
```

All of the checkbox values are lost.  If I examine the raw posted data in Firebug, I see that for some reason both true AND false are posted for the checked boxes "checked" value:

[image]

Comment: What happens if you just did `return View("Index")`?

Comment: The View returns error 500 (null reference) when it attempts to read properties from the Model

Comment: Do you need to return to the Index view?  What about just `return View()`?

Comment: Returns a 404 (the URL has quite a few parameters in there).

Comment: What about changing to `@Html.Label(Model.Modules[i].ModuleName)`?

Comment: Label text renders as `[ ] ModuleName`

Comment: hmmm what about changing this `@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Modules[i].Checked, Model.Modules[i].ModuleName)` to this `@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Modules[i].Checked, m.Modules[i].ModuleName)`?

Comment: do you see an information about your errors in ModelState?

Comment: Only the error created via `ModelState.AddModelError`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697299/asp-net-mvc-why-is-html-checkbox-generating-an-additional-hidden-input for the reason why your postback includes Modules[0].Checked twice.

Comment: The link above explains the reason for a checked checkbox generated using `CheckBoxFor()` returns both `true` and `false`, but what you claiming is not possible (if the 1st checkbox is checked when you submit, it will be checked when you return the view) unless there is other code you have not shown us causing the issue. As a side note, your constructor that is calling a static method is bad practice, and you should remove that, and instead set the value of `Modules` in the GET method - `ProductRequest model = new ProductRequest(){ Modules = // populate it here }; return View(model);`

Comment: @StephenMuecke.  Good advice - thank you.  Out of interest, seeing as you're the C# maestro around here lately, can you advise on any training material (books) for "best practice"?

Comment: Sorry, its been a while since I read a programming book :) - and why did you accept an answer that has nothing to do with your question?

Comment: Using the accepted answer did actually work.  However, the tutorial I previously followed recommended not using an Editor Template for a single-use scenario.  I therefore worked late last night creating a sample solution for you guys to try and spot my mistake.  Annoyingly, the sample solution worked perfectly, so I then stripped my actual solution down to basics, and added each model property back in until the glitch re-occurred.  Bizarrely, the glitch did not occur, so the only difference was a Clean/Rebuild based on yesterday's code.  I'm confused by it nonetheless, but at least its working

Comment: Using an `EditorTemplate` is a good option, but it is no different at all from using a `for` loop, and it certainly does not _solve your issue_. The code you have in your question works perfectly well and does not produce the behavior you claim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the server side, your variable `qd` contains the values you posted from view :
For each `MyProductModule` you post only the `Checked` member.

So when you use  `return View("Index", qd);` you give to the view only the value you have : `Checked` member.

If you want to have the `ModuleName` member, you have to post it alongside to the `Checked` member

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Modules, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "required" })
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Modules.Count; i++)
{
   @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Modules[i].Checked)
   @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Modules[i].ModuleName)
   @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Modules[i].Checked, Model.Modules[i].ModuleName)
}
```

---

Ok, I can't reproduce your error, but I can suggest another way to write it : using an editor template

Instead of the for loop, use  `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Modules)`
You will have something like

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ProcessRequest", "Home"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Modules)
    <input type="submit" value="send" />
}
```

Then create a EditorTemplates folder and a new view named `MyProductModule.cshtml`

[image]

MyProductModule.cshtml :

```
@model MyNamespace.MyProductModule

@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Checked)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ModuleName)
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Checked, Model.ModuleName)
```

Comment: Thanks. Although the label names do persist, the "checked" property is lost, so all boxes become unchecked if the model is returned in the event of me doing AddModelError

Comment: Strangely, if I examine the raw post data, I see this: `Modules[2].Checked=true, Modules[2].Checked=false, Modules[2].ModuleName=Module Three`.  Why would the Checked property appear twice with different values?

Comment: Could you post your exact cshtml please ? 
I use this exact code and it works well

Comment: I've updated the question.  The code is EXACTLY the same as my own