# Submit selected checkboxes only for multiple objects to an MVC controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms

When I have the following form:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="modules" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="modules" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="modules" value="3" />
```

This wil correctly send to the following MVC controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Submit(string[] modules)
{

}
```

But what when the above form is wrapped into an for-loop, like this:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < cart.Events.Count; i++)
{
    <h1>@cart.Events[i].Name</h1>
    <input type="checkbox" name="modules" value="1" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="modules" value="2" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="modules" value="3" />
}
```

With a controller that looks something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Submit(TestObject modules)
{

}

public class TestObject
{
    public string[] modules { get; set; }
}
```

That will not work correctly, because MVC doesn't know how to bind the form data to the object. I want to send the selected values only, because it's not said that the count of module checkboxes is always the same.

How to fix this?

Comment: Your model needs a property say `bool IsSelected` and a property for the value, say `int Value` - refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29542107/pass-list-of-checkboxes-into-view-and-pull-out-ienumerable/29554416#29554416) for an example

Comment: can you also add code of TestObject

Answer (score 0):

All the checkbox have the same names, you could customize the name by : @("modules" + cart.Events[i].Name).