# Passing multi parameters (radio) from view to controller using array

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I would like to post between 55 and 100 items which could be false or true from view to my controller without using Model. This is my code in Razor View:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("User","User",FormMethod.Post,new{enctype="multipart/form-data"}))
    {

        <input type="radio" name="answer1">Choice one</input>
        <input type="radio" name="answer1">Choice two</input>
        <input type="radio" name="answer2">Choice three</input>
        <input type="radio" name="answer2">Choice four</input>

    ....

    <input type="radio" name="answer55">Choice fifty five</input>
    <input type="radio" name="answer55">Choice fifty six</input>

    <button type="submit">Send</button>
                                   }
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> User(Array....)
{
return view();}
```

How can I send all of parameters (radio buttons) using an array to my controller. I appreciate all your solutions.

Comment: Refer the comments in your previous question - your not giving your radio buttons a `value`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe create a view model class that contains an array of `size` bool elements, and then bind each of element to the radio button in Razor page.

```
public class BooleanViewModel
{
   public BooleanViewModel(int size)
   {
      BoolArray = new bool [size];
   }

   public bool [] BoolArray {get; set;} 
}
```

Set your Razor page model: `@model BooleanViewModel`

Then, in Razor you could use `@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.BoolArray[0], "textForButton")` etc.
You could also make some `foreach` loop and go through all items within `model.BoolArray`.

Comment: Size of your bool arrays, 55, 100 or any size you want.

Comment: According to my specification I insist to not use Viewmodel in this particular case. I understand that ViewModel is the propper way but not in this case.

Comment: What is your model now?

Answer (score 0):

Try its:
in your controller:

```
 // GET: Home
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<MyItem> radioItems = new List<MyItem>();
            radioItems.Add(new MyItem() { Caption="radio1", Value="radio1Value"});
            radioItems.Add(new MyItem() { Caption="radio2", Value="radio2Value"});
            radioItems.Add(new MyItem() { Caption="radio3", Value="radio3Value"});
            radioItems.Add(new MyItem() { Caption="radioN", Value="radioNValue"});
            return View(radioItems);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public void IndexPost(List<string> items)
        {
            // todointo item has your selected item
            var x = items;

        }
```

in your cshtml:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("IndexPost", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            foreach (var item in Model)
            {

                <input type="checkbox" name="items" value="@item.Value">@item.Caption
            }

            <button Type="submit">Send</button>

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In View :For Arrays to work, name the Radio buttons in format as below for model binding to work

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home")) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    <input type="radio" name="param[0]" value="one" >
    <input type="radio" name="param[0]" value="two" >
    <input type="radio" name="param[1]" value="three" >
    <input type="radio" name="param[1]" value="four" >
    <input type="radio" name="param[2]" value="five" >
    <input type="radio" name="param[2]" value="six" >
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
}
```

In Post ActionMethod :

```
 [HttpPost]       
 public ActionResult Index(string[] param)
                { //
    }
```

then you will get the value in `param` array in the action method.
You can have as many number of Radio buttons as you wish & ModelBinder will take care of the binding.