# Jquery Function always return count 0 of second parameter

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

i am writing a function in jquery which post the data to controller. currently it is posting form data to controller fine but when i post checkbox list with form data then it send always count 0 in controller here is my code.

```
    function SubmitForm() {
    var studentFormData = $("#frmStudent").serialize();
    debugger;
    var SubjectArraydata = new Array();

    $(".chkSubject:checked").each(function () {
        var row = {
            "SubjectId": $(this).data("id")
        };
        SubjectArraydata.push(row);
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("StudentForm", "Student")',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: studentFormData + JSON.stringify("&subjectData=" + SubjectArraydata),
        async: true,

        success: function (msg) {

        },
        error: function () {

        }
    });
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult StudentForm(Student student, List<Subject> subjectData)
{ 
   return Json(true); 
}
```

any one tell me where is the problem in my code thank you.

Comment: what do you got on controller side?

Comment: i got student form data accurately but subjectData always return 0

Comment: Returns 0 where? It's not clear at all

Comment: Show your controller

Comment: here is my student controller[HttpPost]        
 public ActionResult StudentForm(Student student, List<Subject> subjectData){
 return Json(true);
 }

Comment: Why the `JSON.stringify(...)`? If `subjectData` is supposed to be JSON then only call `JSON.stringify()` on `SubjectArraydata` otherwise it doesn't make much sense...

Comment: Are you really only posting back one property of `Subject` (i.e. `SubjectId` which I assume is an `int`)? If so that will be easier to solve that if you posting back multiple properties of `Subject`.

Comment: i want to posting back only one property. list of int

Comment: `data: { 'student' : studentFormData , 'subjectData' : JSON.stringify(SubjectArraydata) } ` Can you try this??

Comment: @SubhabrataMondal by your code both parameters comes null in controller.

Comment: JSON.stringify({ 'student' : studentFormData , 'subjectData':SubjectArraydata } );   Can you console.log() it? and show us this.

Comment: and try to pass entire thing into data section. @Ammar

Comment: @SubhabrataMondal when i tried this data: { 'student': studentData, 'subjectData': SubjectArraydata}, then student data is null and subject data count is fine but no value in list of subjectData

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cannot mix `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` data (the `contentType` of your `serialize()` method) and `'application/json'` data (the `contentType` of the `JSON.stringify()` method) like that.

Sinve you have confirmed that your only submitting one property of `Subject`, which is `SubjectId` and is typeof `int`, then you can append the `SubjectId` values to the serialized data.

```
var studentFormData = $("#frmStudent").serialize();
$(".chkSubject:checked").each(function () {
    studentFormData += '&' + $.param({ SubjectIds: $(this).data("id") });
};
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("StudentForm", "Student")',
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: studentFormData,
    success: function (msg) {
    },
    error: function () {
    }
});
```

and change your controller method to

```
[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult StudentForm(Student student, List<int> SubjectIds)
{ 
    ....
```

Comment: thank you @Stephen its working fine.thank you for your guaidence.

Comment: Just as a side note, its would be more 'MVC' to actually use a view model and generate the form controls based on that view model so that all that's needed is `$("#frmStudent").serialize()` - for an example of generating a collection of checkboxes, refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29542107/pass-list-of-checkboxes-into-view-and-pull-out-ienumerable/29554416#29554416)

Answer (score 0):

I think you use 'POST' method not correctly. You try to mix sending data as json and as url parameters.

```
data: studentFormData + JSON.stringify("&subjectData=" + SubjectArraydata),
```

what you send in data:

```
[
  {...},
  [{SubjectId: ''}, {SubjectId: ''}]
]
```

or:

```
{
  1: {...},
  subjectData: [{SubjectId: ''}, {SubjectId: ''}]
}
```

or some data sended as json, some in url?

Send all data in json, and dont serialize (jquery do it for you):

```
var data = [strudentFormData, subjectData];
$.ajax(..., data: data, ...);
```

Comment: by this both data is null

Comment: try this: var data = {student: studentFormData, subjectData: subjectArraydata}. both studentFormData and subjectArraydata must be object, not string