# Returning specific table data from the view to the controller? asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

So I have a view which is currently displaying a table of data from the database with a select/selectall checkbox in place.  What I'd like to do is be able to get a list of my CustomerNumbers and whether or not they have been checked and return it to my controller for further action.

[image]

Below is my how my view is currently written. I have tried numberous ways to get this to work and I am stumped.

```
@model MassInactiveInspections.Models.CustomerInfoList

<div class="container">
    <h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>
    <div class="bs-callout bs-callout-info" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">

            @using (Html.BeginForm("SelectedCustomers", "Home", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                <hr />
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
                <div class="form-group">
                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <tr>
                            <th class="active">@Html.DisplayName("Select All?")<input type="checkbox" class="select-all checkbox" name="select-all" /></th>
                            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.CustomerInfoListView.FirstOrDefault().BusinessName)</th>
                            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.CustomerInfoListView.FirstOrDefault().CustomerName)</th>
                            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.CustomerInfoListView.FirstOrDefault().CustomerNumber)</th>                              
                            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.CustomerInfoListView.FirstOrDefault().InspectionCycleDescription)</th>
                            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.CustomerInfoListView.FirstOrDefault().LastInspectionDate)</th>
                            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.CustomerInfoListView.FirstOrDefault().RouteCode)</th>
                            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.CustomerInfoListView.FirstOrDefault().RouteID)</th>
                            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.CustomerInfoListView.FirstOrDefault().SiteNumber)</th>
                            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.CustomerInfoListView.FirstOrDefault().SystemCode)</th>
                        </tr>

                        @foreach (var item in Model.CustomerInfoListView)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td class="active"> <input id="Selected" input type="checkbox" class="select-item checkbox" name="select-item" value="1000" /> </td>
                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BusinessName)</td>
                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CustomerName)</td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CustomerNumber)
                                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CustomerInfoListView.FirstOrDefault().CustomerNumber)
                                </td>
                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InspectionCycleDescription)</td>
                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastInspectionDate)</td>
                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RouteCode)</td>
                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RouteID)</td>
                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SiteNumber)</td>
                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SystemCode)</td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div style="margin-top: 50px">
                        <input type="submit" id="btnLost" class="btn btn-primary" value="Lost"/>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="OOBButton" value="OOB" />
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="RefusedButton" value="Refused" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                }
    </div>
</div>
```

and finally my controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SelectedCustomers(CustomerInfoList 
customerNumberList)
{
    return View("ViewCustomerInfo");
}
```

also here is my javascript for the checkboxes

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SelectedCustomers(CustomerInfoList customerNumberList)
{
    return View("ViewCustomerInfo");
}


        //column checkbox select all or cancel
$("input.select-all").click(function () {
    var checked = this.checked;

    $("input.select-item").each(function (index, item) {
        item.checked = checked;
    });
});

//check selected items
$("input.select-item").click(function () {
    var checked = this.checked;
    console.log(checked);
    checkSelected();
});

//check is all selected
function checkSelected() {
    var all = $("input.select-all")[0];
    var total = $("input.select-item").length;
    var len = $("input.select-item:checked:checked").length;
    console.log("total:" + total);
    console.log("len:" + len);
    all.checked = len === total;
}
});
```

Comment: Seems like you need a new property on your `CustomerInfoListView` view model named `Selected`, then where your `<input />` is you can use `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.CustomerInfoListView[i].Selected)` in your loop (where `i` is the index position of that item). Then you would have access to that data when you post to your controller.

Comment: You cannot use a `foreach` loop for generating form controls for a collection - refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943). And to handle your checkboxes and post back the selections - refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29542107/pass-list-of-checkboxes-into-view-and-pull-out-ienumerable/29554416#29554416). And you will need some javascript to handle your 'Select All' checkbox

Comment: @StephenMuecke Could he keep the `foreach` and use `var i = Model.CustomerInfoListView.IndexOf(item);` to get his index position for each iteration?

Comment: @zgood, No that will not work. It will not generate the correct `name` attribute for binding (which needs to be `name="CustomerInfoListView[0].CustomerNumber"`, `name="CustomerInfoListView[1].CustomerNumber"` etc.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I think you misunderstood what I was asking. Please look at the [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PU99hw) (just the Razor part with the `foreach` loop). You see I can use a `foreach` and still get the index value to generate the correct names with the `@Html` Razor helpers. I know that works I have used it successfully before, I was more or less wondering if it was less efficient than a normal `for` with an `i++`. I am just trying to show you that you **can** use a `foreach` to generate controls for a collection, you just have to manage the index value yourself

Comment: @zgood That's just adding unnecessary code to mimic using a `for` loop, and it will only work if the model is `IList<T>` so what would be the point. And your fiddle does not even compile :)

Comment: Well you could `.ToList` it or setup your own `var i = 0;` and `i++` each iteration. I agree that a normal `for` is more suited... I'm just show you that you can do it. So when you say _cannot_ you really mean _shouldn't_ ;) (Oh I didn't make the fiddle to compile lol... just to show some Razor... I didn't touch the controller or VM)

Comment: @zgood, You can shoot yourself in the foot too. Why would you want to? And the _cannot_ was in relation to the question

Comment: I really appreciate the responses and am working through them.  I added the javascript for the checkboxes.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is the best way to handle it but I simply added the fields that I wanted into a HiddenFor helper and they were returned to my the appropriate controller.  Thanks everyone for the help.

```
 @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.additionalCustomerInfoListView[i].CustomerNumber)
```