# select property of selectlistitem always false

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I have a view page to show a multi select check box. Here is the code to show that.

```
@{                                                                                                
    foreach (SelectListItem item in Model.VendorCategoryList)                                                                                                
    {                                                                                                    
        string name = item.Text;                                                                                                    
        bool chkResult = item.Selected;//Model.VendorCategoryList;                                                                                                    
        <tr class="VendorCategoryClassSave">                                                                                                        
            <td style="width: 4%;text-align:right;padding-right:15px;">                                                                                                            
                <label>                                                                                                                
                    @Html.CheckBox("chkVendorCategoryDetailId_" + item.Value, chkResult, new { @class = "chkVendorCategoryDetailClass" })                                                                                                            
                </label>                                                                                                        
            </td>                                                                                                        
            <td style="width: 10%;">                                                                                                            
                <label>@Html.Label(name)</label>                                                                                                        
            </td>                                                                                                    
        </tr>                                                                                                
    }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult NewVendor(int custid = 0)
{
    List<SelectListItem> VendorCategory = _commonRepository.VendorCategory
        .AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.status == 1).Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = x.catename,
            Value = x.cateid.ToString(),
            Selected=false
        }).ToList();
    foreach(SelectListItem item in VendorCategory)
    {
        item.Selected = setSelectedcategory(Convert.ToInt32(item.Value), custid);
    }
    var model = new HomeViewModel
    {
        VendorCategoryList = new SelectList(VendorCategory, "Value", "Text", "Selected")
    };
    return View("../Masters/View_Vendor", model);
}
```

Model

```
public HomeViewModel
{
    public SelectList VendorCategoryList { get; set; }
}
```

What happens is that even though I set "true" for the Selected attribute in the selectlistitem it always shows as false. See the images below [pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPJ8O.png). In the pic1 it says clearly that the selected property is "true". But when I select each item from the model in foreach loop, it says that the selected property is "false". See pic2. [Pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhAE6.png). Can you please help me what I am doing wrong.

This is only happening in the foreach loop. Out side of loop it shows the correct value(true). Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd better use `ViewBag`instead of creating a different view model. You can just send this list to view using `ViewBag.selectList = VendorCategory` and then use this list like `foreach item in (SelectListItem)ViewBag.selectList`

Comment: You setting `VendorCategoryList` to a new `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` by using `new SelectList()` which wipes out all your `Selected` values (it would need to be just `VendorCategoryList = VendorCategory`). But using `SelectListItem` is not appropriate for this and almost everything else in your code is awful practice. Suggest you refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29542107/pass-list-of-checkboxes-into-view-and-pull-out-ienumerable/29554416#29554416) for how to do this correctly

Comment: You can create your own view model instead of using select list. This is not place to use select list.

Comment: @LabLab I got that by using ViewBag.selectList. Thanks

Comment: Using `ViewBag` is a terrible option! And none of this can ever bind to your model when you submit, and you can never get any validation, etc etc.