# Is it possible to Submit a list of GUIDS with MVC based on checkbox?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, checkbox, html-helper

So i'm facing this problem that I don't remember how to solve it, but i'm sure it needs some handcraft to achieve it by using razor (without jquery)

Basically you have

**Model**

```
public class MyModel {
    --Post will write here:
    public List<Guid> SelectedIds {get; set;}

    --This is the actual list of values, ids, etc...
    public List<Option> Options {get;}
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Save (MyModel model)
```

**Class Option**

```
public class Option {
    public String Name {get; set;}
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
}
```

**Question:**

I would like to have a list of checkboxes binded to "Options" property, but when I submit the form, I would like to retrieve IDS only of the selected values, would be great if I could put them inside "SelectedIds" property.

Any clue how to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Refer [Pass List of Checkboxes into View and Pull out IEnumerable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29542107/pass-list-of-checkboxes-into-view-and-pull-out-ienumerable/29554416#29554416)

Comment: hmm, so that approach might not have my expected result, but is actually acceptable. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, handcrafted way might be like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < Model.Options.Count; i++)
  {
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Options[i].ID)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Options[i].IsSelected)
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Options[i].IsSelected, Model.Options[i].Name)
  }
```

But in addition, I needed to create a new class for my "Option", to include the IsSelected flag. (Usually I don't have this field as a value in my database, it will result in the representation of an MxN record)

Also, Class Option is auto-generated, so bad idea to change it, instead inheritance will be enought.

```
public class OptionSelectable : Option {
    public Boolean IsSelected {get; set;}
}
```

And that's it, thanks @Stephen Muecke for the tip