# CheckboxFor - cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

**Model**

```
public partial class Job_Governance
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int IDJob{ get; set; }
    public int IDGovernance { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Job> job { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Governance> governance { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult AddJobGovernance()
{
    ViewBag.IDGovernance = new SelectList(db.Governances, "ID", "Name");
    var data = db.Job.ToList();
    Job_Governance jg = new Job_Governance();
    jg.IDJob = data;
    return View(jg);
}
```

**View**

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.job.Count(); i++)
{                            
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.job, new { @value = Model.job[i].ID })
    <i></i>@Model.job[i].Ten
}
```

I need to get a list of jobs from the checkbox to save to the database, eg :

```
ID         IDJob            IDGovernance
1            1                    1
2            2                    1
3            3                    1
4            6                    1
5            20                   1
```

I am learning asp.net mvc, got this error hoping everyone helps purpose for decentralization for project, but I can not get list job from checkbox for.

Comment: You cannot bind a checkbox to a complex object (which is what `Job` is) , and `CheckBoxFor()` is for binding to a `bool` property

Comment: If you want to create a list of checkboxes, then suggest you start by reading [Pass List of Checkboxes into View and Pull out IEnumerable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29542107/pass-list-of-checkboxes-into-view-and-pull-out-ienumerable/29554416#29554416)

Comment: You don't show the model constructor, and I don't see you set the model `job` property. In second the `IDJob` property is integer, but you are trying to assign the property value to `data` that is `List`.