# ASP.NET MVC Update entity database on checkbox, passing in checkbox name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, checkbox, onclick

I have a "to do list" where the tasks (assignments) are stored as records in a database. One of the elements in the `Assignment` model is `Complete`. The page outputs all of the values in the `Assignments` (`List<Assignment>`) table using a for loop, along with a checkbox on the end.

```
@using (var ctx = new AssignmentContext())
        {
            var assignmentList = ctx.Assignments.ToList();
            foreach (Assignment assignment in assignmentList)
                <tr name ="@assignment.AssignmentId">
                    <td>@assignment.CourseName</td>
                    <td>@assignment.AssignmentName</td>
                    <td>@assignment.DueDate</td>
                    <td>@assignment.Value</td>
                    <td>@Html.CheckBox()</td>
                </tr>
        }
```

I want to change the state of  the `bool Assignment.Complete` in the database on the click of the checkbox. I am pretty new to web development and the mixing of HTML and C# is what confuses me here. How do I have a `onClick` call a controller function and when I do, how do I pass it the specific row after the for loop has already ran. Do I NEED JS here?

Comment: Please provide the sample code (or minimal code) to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Suggest you read [Pass List of Checkboxes into View and Pull out IEnumerable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29542107/pass-list-of-checkboxes-into-view-and-pull-out-ienumerable/29554416#29554416), but if you do want to do this one at a time, then using ajax to call a server method would be an option.

Answer (score 2):

try it:
CsHtml:

```
  @using (var ctx = new AssignmentContext())
            {
                var assignmentList = ctx.Assignments.ToList();
                foreach (Assignment assignment in assignmentList)
                    <tr name ="@assignment.AssignmentId">
                        <td>@assignment.CourseName</td>
                        <td>@assignment.AssignmentName</td>
                        <td>@assignment.DueDate</td>
                        <td>@assignment.Value</td>
                        <td>@Html.CheckBox(assignment.AssignmentId, assignment.Complete, new {@id= assignment.AssignmentId,onclick= "complete($(this))" })</td>
                    </tr>
            }
```

Java Script:

```
<script>
    function complete(selector) {
        var assignmentId = selector.attr('id');

        $.get('/Assignment/Complete', { id: assignmentId, checked: selector.checked}, function() {
          alert('successfull')  
        })

    }

</script>
```

Controller:

```
public async Task<JsonResult> Complete(int id,bool checked)
        {

            @using(var ctx = new AssignmentContext())
            {
            var assignment =   ctx.Assignments.Find(id);
                assignment.Complete = checked;
                ctx.SaveChanges();


            }
            return Json(new { isSuccess =true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: This is kind of the opposite of what I want to do, although I will want to do this too. This sets the checkbox status to whatever the value in the database is. I need to change the database to whatever the state of the checkbox becomes on the click.

Comment: Ok,I Update my answer. I hope it's useful

Comment: it's not helpful?