# MVC 5 and the 'Get Shit Done Kit' checkbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I bought the 'Get Shit Done' UI kit for my latest MVC 5 project, but i can't get the checkbox to work. I am trying to use it for the "Remember me" checkbox on the standard MVC 5 login page.

```
<label class="checkbox checkbox-blue" for="RememberMe">
  <input type="checkbox" value="" id="RememberMe" name="RememberMe" data-toggle="checkbox" checked>
        Remember me
</label>
```

It doesn't work though. MVC can't parse the value to anything meaningful.

EDIT:
To elaborate a bit. Using the standard Html.CheckboxFor syntax doesn't generate a checkbox the way the UI kit i am using expects.
The UI kit needs the checkbox to be in the format specified above, since there is some javascript-code that needs to work on it.

Is there perhaps a way to get the mvc html-helpers to generate a bound checkbox in that custom format?

Comment: Please define "doesn't work". Does the chekcbox get rendered correctly? Do you get the value back on the server?

Comment: Your checkbox does not have a value. Assuming you want to bind to a `bool` then it would need to be `value="true"`. But why not use `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)` and `@Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe, "Remember me")` so you get 2 way binding out of the box.

Comment: Which part of the html is relevant? If you just want to add the `data-toggle="checkbox"` then its just `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe, new { data_toggle="checkbox" })`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Html helpers

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.SomeBooleanProperty, new { @checked = "checked" })
```

Please look at the link below

[link to article on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12674572/proper-usage-of-net-mvc-html-checkboxfor)

Comment: You do not set `new { @checked = "checked" }` when using `@Html.CheckBoxFor()`. The `checked` attribute is set based on the property your bind to.

Comment: @AshleyMedway, No. If the value of `RememberMe` is `false` when the model is passed to the view, then `new { @checked = "checked" }` is just ignored - the checkbox is not checked. That's how model binding works - it binds to your property.