# Model Binding a checkbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, model-binding

I have always used the MVC model binding so this is new for me. I have a class and mvc razor form.

```
public class Student
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public bool? IsNew { get; set; }
}
```

My mvc razorpage

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" name="isNew" id="isNew">Import
    </label>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
     <label for="firstName">FirstName</label>
     <input class="form-control" name="firstName" id="firstName"/>
  </div>
```

The way I have binded the firstName was

```
student.FirstName = request.Form.Get("firstName");
```

But I have not been able to use the same technique for checkbox? 
I tried using

```
       student.IsNew = request.Form.GetValues("isNew");
       student.IsNew = request.Form.Get("isNew");
```

How can I do this?

Comment: If you're using modelbinding, shouldn't you just have a `Student` parameter on your action method?
See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12674572/proper-usage-of-net-mvc-html-checkboxfor 
for better syntax of your razor page

Comment: Your not binding to your property. A checkbox without a value posts back `"on"` which cannot be bound to a `boolean` property. And if the checkbox is unchecked, nothing is posted. Why are you not using model binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Morning,
Just an update on how I managed to solve this:
I looked at the values that is coming from the form.

I used this to get model binding work.

```
       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.Form.Get("isNew")))
        {
            vehicle.IsNew = true;
        }
        else
        {
            vehicle.IsNew = false;
        }
```

And for future reference, always use mvc model binders

Answer (score 2):

You should be using MVC Model binding which makes it easier for you.

Model binding reads all the posted data , querystring values etc and build an object for you. Model binding allow your controller code to remain cleanly separated from the dirtiness of interrogating the request and its associated environment.

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
   var vm = new Student();
   return View(vm);
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Student model)
{
   //You can check model.IsNew and model.FirstName properties here
   // TO DO : Save and Redirect to a success message action method
   // Ex : return RedirectToAction("SavedSuccessfully");
}
```

And your strongly typed razor view

```
@model Student
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <lable>FirstName </lable>@Html.TextBoxFor(d=>d.FirstName)
    <lable>FirstName </lable>@Html.TextBoxFor(d => d.LastName)
    <label>New ? </label>@Html.CheckBoxFor(g=>g.IsNew)
    @Html.HiddenFor(d=>d.Id)
    <p>
        <input id="BtnAdd" name="myButton" type="submit" value="Add" />
    </p>
}
```

Comment: I have always used MVC model binding but I am debugging this issue for legacy code. I may have to revert the codes and use MVC model binding instead.

Answer (score 1):

When returning IList and only having to select a few students and pass them to [HttpPost] public ActionResult Student(IFormCollection form, int[] SelectedSID), here is what you can add in your View.

```
@model IList<MvcDWOL.Data.Student>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Add Students";
}

@Html.Partial("_StatusMessage", @ViewData["StatusMessage"])

<div class="container"">
<div class="top-buffer"></div>
<div class="panel panel-primary" style="border:none">
<div class="panel-heading panel-head">Live</div>
<div class="panel-body">

@using (Html.BeginForm("AddEdit", "Student", FormMethod.Post))
{

        <div class="form-actions no-color">
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary"/> 
        </p>
       </div>

<table> 
<tbody>
  <thead>
        <tr>
             <th>
                Add (checkbox)
            </th>
            <th>
               Name
            </th>
            <th>
               Type
            </th>
             <th style="display:none">
                  Start Date
                </th>
             <th>
                   Start Time
                </th>
              <th style="display:none">
                  End Date
                </th>
                <th>
                   End Time
                </th>   
        </tr>
    </thead>

   @if (Model.Any())
  { 
        foreach (var item in Model)
        {

                <tr>
                <th  style="display:none">
                <input id="item@(item.ID)" type="hidden" 
                name="SelectedSID"
                value="@item.ID"
                /> 
                </th>
                <th>   
                <div style="zoom:1.5;">
                    @Html.CheckBox("IsAdded",@item.IsAdded)
                 </div> 
                </th>
                <th>

                  @item.Name
                 <input id="item@(item.Name)" type="hidden"  name="Name" value="@item.Name"/>
                </th>
                <th>
                  @item.Type.TypeName
                <input id="item@(item.TypeID)" type="hidden"  name="TypeID" value="@item.TypeID"/> 
                </th>
                <th>
                   @item.StartTimeValue
                 <input id="item@(item.StartTime)" type="hidden"  name="StartTime" value="@item.StartTime"/> 
                 <input id="item@(item.StartTimeValue)" type="hidden"  name="StartTimeValue" value="@item.StartTimeValue"/> 
                </th>
                <th>
                   @item.EndTimeValue
                 <input id="item@(item.EndTime)" type="hidden"  name="EndTime" value="@item.EndTime"/> 
                 <input id="item@(item.EndTimeValue)" type="hidden"  name="EndTimeValue" value="@item.EndTimeValue"/> 
                </th>
            </tr>

         }
   }         
  </tbody>
</table>
        @Html.ValidationSummary()
        <div class="form-actions no-color">
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" /> 
        </p>
      </div>

}


</div></div></div>
```