# ASP.NET MVC checkbox always false

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I made an asp.net website, but the checkbox is always false. Why is this so?

Model:

```
 public string Username { get; set; }
 public string Password { get; set; }
 public bool Remember { get; set; }
```

CSHTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("Remember me?")
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Remember)
 </div>
```

The `Remember` property is always false, if the checkbox is checked then `Remember`is still false.

Comment: Do you ever set it to true?

Comment: No, if the checkbox is checked then also false.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I got the same issue, I fixed it by writing html checkbox tag, giving it the name same as property name, and value = true, if the checkbox is not checked no need to worry as it won't be submitted anyway, 
in your case this will be it

`<input type="checkbox" name="Remember" value="true" />`

Comment: The is the only way I can see to do it.  `CheckBoxFor` just plain doesn't work.  Who knows if it ever did.

Comment: I just try this on Chrome. Updating the form send true on the saving even if you don't check the checkbox.

Answer (score 6):

With Razor, I had the same problem. What worked for me was taking off the `value="xxx"` tag.  Then it functioned normally.

Does ***not*** work:

```
 <input class="form-check-input" value="true" asp-for="Answer.aIsCorrect" />
```

Works:

```
 <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="Answer.aIsCorrect" />
```

Answer (score -1):

The first parameter is not checkbox value but rather view model binding for the checkbox hence:

@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.SomeBooleanProperty, new { @checked = "checked" });
The first parameter must identify a boolean property within your model (it's an Expression not an anonymous method returning a value) and second property defines any additional HTML element attributes. I'm not 100% sure that the above attribute will initially check your checkbox, but you can try. But beware. Even though it may work you may have issues later on, when loading a valid model data and that particular property is set to false.

Source and additional info:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12674731/3397630

Hope it will helpful for you ,kindly let me know your thoughts or feedbacks

Thanks
Karthik

Comment: That is exactly what OP already has! - a `bool` property named `Remember` and `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Remember)` (and setting `new { @checked = "checked" } is pointless - its the value of the property which determines if its checked