# @Html.CheckBoxFor is enabled or not and get the true or false in controller based on selection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

In Cshtml file I have created a checkbox and using that true or false value of check box, need to write the logic in controller

In cshtml file

`@Html.Checkboxfor(m=>m.isChecked,new {id="isChecked"})   @Html.Label("Ischecked",new {id="lblIsChecked", @class = "control-label"`

In Model.cs

`public bool isChecked {get;set;}`

In controller

`Model model=new Model();`

`If(model.isChecked == true)`
`{`

`//Logic to write`
`}`

While checking isCheked variable in controller, I'm getting only false. Clarify this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ASP.NET MVC checkbox always false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44134973/asp-net-mvc-checkbox-always-false)

Answer (score 0):

Below is a work demo, you can refer to it:

In Controller:

```
       public IActionResult Index()
        {
            Model model = new Model();
            return View(model);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index(Model model)
        {          
            if (model.isChecked == true)
            {
                //Logic to write
            }
            return View();
        }
```

view:

```
@model Model
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.isChecked)
@Html.Label("ischecked","isChecked",new {id="lblIsChecked", @class = "control-label"})

<br/>
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
}
```

result:

[image]