# How to use Bootstrap Toggle with Html.CheckBoxFor?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

All I want to know is the proper syntax for using Bootstrap Toggle with the Html.CheckBoxFor HTML helper in ASP.NET MVC.

> < input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Yes"
>   data-off="No" data-width="15" data-height="15"  data-onstyle="success"
>   data-offstyle="danger" data-style="ios">

**The question is how to use the Html.CheckBoxFor + Bootstrap Toggle, not the Html.CheckBoxFor himself**

> @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Active, new {
>   **?Bootstrap Toggle?** })

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12674572/proper-usage-of-net-mvc-html-checkboxfor Duplicate?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proper usage of .net MVC Html.CheckBoxFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12674572/proper-usage-of-net-mvc-html-checkboxfor)

Comment: The question is how to use the Html.CheckBoxFor + Bootstrap Toggle, not the Html.CheckBoxFor himself

Comment: `@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Active, new { data_toggle="toggle", data_on="Yes", ..... })` (note the `_` will be converted to `-` in the generated html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a list of checkbox and use Bootstrap Toggle like that:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => item.isSelected, new { id = "espSelected_" + 
  item.idEspecialidad, data_toggle = "toggle", data_onstyle = "success" })
```

Do not forget to use this:

```
<link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" 
    rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
```