# Checkbox always pass true value to controller MVC .Net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I'm using a checkbox to handle allow Ordering function, which generates HTML code below:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("EditFarm", "CustomerManagement", FormMethod.Post))
{
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
  @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
  @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AllowOrder)

 <div>
   <label for="allowOrder">Allow Ordering</label>
   <br />
   <input type="checkbox" id="allowOrder" name="AllowOrder" value="true" @(Model.AllowOrder ? "checked" : "") />
 </div>
....
}
```

The problem is checkbox `AllowerOrder` always pass `true` value to Controller even when it's `unchecked`

This is code in Controller:

```
public ActionResult EditFarm([Bind(Include = "Id, ERPCustomerCode, ERPId, CategoryId, Size, Large, OtherId, AllowOrder")] NewFarm farm)
        {
           ...
        }
```

Tried the debug, received model always have `AllowerOrder = true`. 
[image]

Is there any issue in my code? Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: On top of Yauhen's comment, your checkbox doesn't seem bound to `AllowOrder`. This one is more likely bound to it: `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AllowOrder)`

Comment: You should use `@Html.CheckboxFor`. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12674572/proper-usage-of-net-mvc-html-checkboxfor)

Comment: Most likely `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AllowOrder)` overrides the checkbox value because it generates `<input type="hidden" name="AllowOrder" />`. Note that both elements have same `name` attribute.

Comment: This is because value is "true" which is sent in post. bind the value attribute to your model property i.e. AllowOrder

Comment: @KumarLachhani would you please show me by code? thought it's already `bound by '@(Model.AllowOrder ? "checked" : "")`

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto so I deleted `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AllowOrder)` but it doesn't work then

Comment: I recommend using `@Html.CheckBoxFor`, what thing doesn't work? Is that related to `checked` attribute? I think just putting `name` attribute with `input` element is not enough to bind checkbox value for viewmodel property.

Comment: Agree with @TetsuyaYamamoto, 
a. Delete @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AllowOrder)
b. Use @Html.CheckBoxFor instead of ```<input type="checkbox" id="allowOrder" name="AllowOrder" value="true" @(Model.AllowOrder ? "checked" : "") />```

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Oh thanks, I've just tried using `@Html.CheckBoxFor `, and it works now. But it seems like `<input type="checkbox" id="allowOrder" name="AllowOrder" value="true" @(Model.AllowOrder ? "checked" : "") />` should work cause I used to use it for `<input type="text"`, and all worked well.

Comment: could ya make an official answer for me to vote it as right one? Thank you so much. @TetsuyaYamamoto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most possible cause is you're binding to `AllowOrder` property using `HiddenFor` helper before using `<input type="checkbox" />`, which will generate input elements in this order:

```
<input name="AllowOrder" type="hidden" ... />

<input type="checkbox" id="allowOrder" name="AllowOrder" value="true" ... />
```

Since there are 2 input elements with same `name` attribute value, only the first `<input>` element will bound to viewmodel property, which contains `true` value in your case. Instead of creating checkbox manually with `<input>` tag and hidden field separately, you should use `@Html.CheckBoxFor()` helper and toggle `checked` attribute using a helper function below or use ternary operator:

```
public object SetChecked(bool value)
{
    if (value)
    {
        return new { id = "allowOrder", @checked = "checked" };
    }
    else
    {
        return new { id = "allowOrder" };
    }
}
```

**Checkbox**

```
@* alternative 1 *@

@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.AllowOrder, @(SetChecked(Model.AllowOrder)))

@* alternative 2 *@

@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.AllowOrder, new { id = "allowOrder", @checked = @(Model.AllowOrder ? "checked" : "") })
```

**Note:** `checked` is a C# keyword, hence it needs to be escaped with `@` to set it as HTML attribute of rendered `<input type="checkbox" />`.

Comment: Note that the `SetChecked` function (as you wrote it) is only usable for one checkbox, as you set the `id` without a parameter. Hence I would rather use the second alternative, or add an `id` parameter.