# ASP.NET MVC CheckBoxFor "Cannot Convert from bool to system.linq.<type,bool>"

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

I'm simply trying to get a checkbox to display checked if a property (bool) is set to true.

This is a list of items, so I'm doing a for each in the list, then grabbing the property I'm checking `HasImage`. If that is true, I want a checked box for each item.

I'm getting the error

> Argument type 'bool' is not assignable to parameter type system.linq.expressions.expression-system.func rma-vm,bool

[image]

What exactly is going on?

My code:

```
@foreach (var item in model.rmalist)
    <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(item.HasImage)<td>
```

Comment: Try this `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.HasImage, new { @checked = "checked" });`, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12674572/proper-usage-of-net-mvc-html-checkboxfor

Answer (score 0):

Html.CheckBoxFor get Func from inputs . You should try this :

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m=> m.HasImage)
```

Comment: This doesn't work because "HasImage" is inside a list of RmaObjects,  

M => m.RmaObjects  is all that shows up, because the hasimage property is inside of it.  I thought doing the foreach loop would clear it up but I guess not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below syntax to select/un-select check box based on the value

if HasImage is nullable then below format

```
@Html.CheckBox("HasImage", (item.HasImage?? false) ? item.HasImage: false)
```

if HasImage is not nullable then simply keep the value

```
@Html.CheckBox("HasImage", item.HasImage)
```