# Is there a way I can add and bind checkboxes to my MVC Table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I am trying to add a checkbox so I can selects a row from my list and from there use that row to generate a letter.
I was wondering how I would be able to add a checkbox and bind it to the data I have tried a few ways using something similar to:

```
checkbox(m => m[i].Lesson)
```

However it would never accept the i in brackets and come up with an error. below is the layout of my index for the lessons model currently.

Here is the Lessons Index:

```
@model IEnumerable<FinalMusicApp.Models.Lesson>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}


<h2>Lessons</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Students", FormMethod.Get))
{
    //Search options
    <b>Search Options: </b> @Html.RadioButton("Option", "Instrument")<text>Instrument</text>@Html.RadioButton("Option", "Tutor")<text>Tutor</text>@Html.RadioButton("Option", "Term")<text>Term</text>@Html.TextBox("Search")
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" />
}



<form method="post">
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IsChecked)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LessonDate)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LessonTime)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Duration.TimeTaken)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Instrument.InstrumentName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Letter.Paid)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Student.FullName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Tutor.TutorName)
            </th>
            <th>
                CRUD
            </th>
            <th>
                Make a letter
            </th>
        </tr>


        @foreach (var item in Model)

        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.IsChecked)
                </td>

                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LessonDate)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LessonTime)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Duration.TimeTaken)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Instrument.InstrumentName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Letter.Paid)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Student.FullName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Tutor.TutorName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.LessonId }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.LessonId }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.LessonId })

                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Generate Letter", "Create", "Letters")
                </td>


            </tr>
        }

    </table>

</form>
```

Comment: Have you tried `@Html.CheckBoxFor`?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12674572/1188513

Comment: yeah i tried @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsChecked)

Comment: Can you get the value of `IsChecked` from view to your contoller ?

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to add a checkbox so I can selects a row from my list

Do you want something like below?

In the view add a checkbox, for example I use the property CourseName in my model instead, you can use your property:

```
 @Html.CheckBox("CourseName", new { value = item.CourseName })
 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CourseName)
```

Then in the controller, we can get CourseName  value, and get other property value accord to the CourseName, but we need load the list again, we cannot send the full list from view to controller :

```
var courserow = model.FirstOrDefault(m => m.CourseName == CourseName);
```

result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To project a line onto a plane in three-dimensional space, you can use the following formula. Let's consider a line given by a point
�
P on the line and a direction vector
�
v for the line. The line can be parameterized by the parameter
�
t:

## Line:
�
(
�
)

�
+
�
⋅
�
Line: r(t)=P+t⋅v

Now, let's consider a plane given by a point
�
Q on the plane and a normal vector
�
n for the plane. The plane can be described by the equation:

## Plane:
�
⋅
(
�
−
�
)

0
Plane: n⋅(r−Q)=0

The projection of the line onto the plane, denoted as
proj
(
�
)
proj(r), can be calculated using the following formula:

## proj
(
�
)

�
+
(
(
�
−
�
)
⋅
�
�
⋅
�
)
⋅
�
proj(r)=Q+(
v⋅n
(P−Q)⋅n
​
)⋅v

Here:

�
r is a point on the line.
�
P is a point on the line.
�
v is the direction vector of the line.
�
Q is a point on the plane.
�
n is the normal vector of the plane.
⋅
⋅ represents the dot product.
This formula involves vector operations such as dot products and scalar multiplication. It provides the point on the plane that is closest to the given line, forming the projection of the line onto the plane.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).