# How to set a CheckBox by default Checked in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am using CheckBox in my ASP.Net MVC project,

i want to set checkBox by default checked,

My CheckBox is

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.As, new { @checked = "checked" })
```

but its not working,,,,

Comment: Set your model property to true

Answer (score 82, accepted):

In your controller action rendering the view you could set the `As` property of your model to true:

```
model.As = true;
return View(model);
```

and in your view simply:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.As);
```

Now since the As property of the model is set to true, the CheckBoxFor helper will generate a checked checkbox.

Comment: I want to checked without changing model.as value in Controller..
how to change value in view

Comment: The correct way to achieve that is to set the value in the controller. That's how the CheckBoxFor helper is designed to be used. If you don't want to follow the best practices you could always manually generate the checkbox in the view with a hardcoded `checked="checked"` attribute.

Comment: i tried with @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.As, new { @checked = "true" }) but its not working

Comment: Yes, it's not working because the helper doesn't support this attribute. It uses the value of the `As` property on your model which, as I already explained in my answer, should be set in your controller action. But I repeat once again, if you don't want to follow this recommended approach you should hardcode your checkbox manually: `<input type="checkbox" name="As" value="true" checked="checked" /><input type="hidden" name="As" value="false" />`.

Comment: After changing model.as value in controller its affecting other view, that's why i want to set in that particular view,

Answer (score 54):

Old question, but another "pure razor" answer would be:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.As, htmlAttributes: new { @checked = true} )
```

Comment: This has no effect if the model value is "false" (the checkbox is rendered unchecked) and is not needed if the model value is "true," so what is the point of this code?

Comment: What about when it's null? (`bool ?`)

Comment: It's indeed useful on Create New view. If you want to create or add new data, sometimes you want a default value. For example field for "Marital Status" - maybe you want to set "Yes" or "Checked" as default value on the form.

Comment: This does not model bind properly and was the root of a bug I was just working on (.net framework 4.6 at least)...This should not have this many upvotes

Comment: That being said, this can be leveraged for a hacky solution if your architecture is bad enough that you cannot quickly do Darin's (the approved) answer. You can use this line *in conjunction* with defaulting the backing boolean property to true `public bool As { get; set; } = true;` but I pray you are not working with spaghetti code like I am...

Answer (score 3):

You could set your property in the model's constructor

```
public YourModel()
{
    As = true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
@Html.CheckBox("yourId", true, new { value = Model.Ischecked })
```

This will certainly work

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution is using jQuery:

```
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            PrepareCheckbox();
        });
        function PrepareCheckbox(){
            document.getElementById("checkbox").checked = true;
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use viewbag with the same variable name in the Controller. E.g if the variable is called "IsActive" and I want this to default to true on the "Create" form, on the Create Action I set the value ViewBag.IsActive = true;

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.IsActive = true;
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My way is `@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.As, new { @value= "true" })` (meaning is checked)

Answer (score 0):

In razor, set value first.

```
@{model.As = true;}
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.As)
```