# How to Set Checkbox Value to True by Default using Html Helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm using the below given table in Partial view and I want to set the value of checkboxes to true by default using Html Helper. I have tried

```
<input type="checkbox" value="@Model[i].IsSelected" checked="checked" />
```

but it passes the false value to controller even if I checked it to true. Here is my table code. .

```
@model List<SchoolManagment.Models.tbl_Student>

<table id="tableforposting" class="table table-hover table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Sr#</th>
            <th class="col-sm-1"></th>
            <th>STUDENT NAME</th>
            <th>ROLL NO.</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td class="col-sm-1 text-center">
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x[i].IsSelected)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].Name)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].Roll_No)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x[i].Roll_No)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Controller action, you can set the Checkbox model property **true** to create the checked checkbox.

```
public ActionResult Index(Register model)
{
    model.Terms = true;
    return View(model);
}
```

In View,

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Terms)
```

For reference, [How to set a CheckBox by default Checked in ASp.Net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16435448/how-to-set-a-checkbox-by-default-checked-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: Thank u @Parag Turkar.. U saved my day..