# strongly type check box not working in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i am trying to create strongly type checkbox but this not working properly and
checkbox not show is checked but flag is true in model 
please suggest me
code:-

```
 @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Active, new { @checked =true})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a CheckBox by default Checked in ASP.Net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16435448/how-to-set-a-checkbox-by-default-checked-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: @Esko i am not set default checkbox ,i want to set checkBox by my get database value

Comment: @DipGirase set the value in the model Controller-side _before_ you get to the View. The code `@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model. Active);` will then represent  that value. Also, `Active` must be a `bool` type. (this is as per the solution @Esko suggested)

Answer (score 0):

Use a [EditorFor](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/htmlhelper-editor-editorfor)

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Active, new { Value = model.Active})
```

or

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Active)
```

> **As other users have said:** Set the value of Active on the model Controller-side before you get to the View and also, Active must be a
>   boolean type. (this is as per the solution @Esko suggested)