# How to get email checkbox checked by default?

Tags: html, razor, sitecore

I have defined connection alternatives for email and SMS. I want to have email checked by default.
I wondered if I can add attribute checked in Razor without changing model or controller.
Because if I use plain HTML, then it works but with Razor and when I inspection the page, there is no checked attribute.

```
@checked = "checked"
@checked = checked
@checked = "true"
@checked = true
new{@checked = "checked"}

<div class="checkbox-wrapper">
                    <label>
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-check-input", id = "E-post", @checked = "checked" })
                        <label for="E-post">E-post</label>
                    </label>
                </div>
```

email checkbox checked when the page is loaded

Comment: @Model.Email = true;

Comment: Are the first few "lines of code" all the combinations you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

I found that ***CheckBoxFor*** does not have an attribute ***checked***. The solution is to use ***CheckBox*** and then the second attribute is the boolean true or false which is the answer to the attribute ***isChecked***.

```
@Html.CheckBox("name",true,new {@class="className",id="idName"})
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller action,set `Model.Email=true;`.

this link might help you, [set a CheckBox by default Checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16435448/how-to-set-a-checkbox-by-default-checked-in-asp-net-mvc)