# Save checkbox data in SQL Server using MVC

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, checkbox, boolean, explicit

I use MVC and want to save the checkbox data in boolean form in sql server. 
The error is in the Customer Form Model when I try to use the Razor view for the checkboxes model.

The error is:

> CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool?' to 'bool'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Controller Code:

```
public ActionResult SaveRecord(CustomerCount cc)
{
    try
    {
        CustomerCounterDBEntities1 dbs = new CustomerCounterDBEntities1();
        List<CustomerInfo> infos = dbs.CustomerInfoes.ToList();
        ViewBag.CustomerInfoList = new SelectList(infos, "Name", "Mobile");
        CustomerInfo ct = new CustomerInfo();
        ct.CustomerID = cc.CustomerID;
        ct.Name = cc.Name;
        ct.Mobile = cc.Mobile;
        ct.Email = cc.Email;
        ct.Comments = cc.Comments;
        ct.Western_Union = cc.Western_Union;
        ct.Ria = cc.Ria;
        ct.Money_Gram = cc.Money_Gram;
        ct.Intel = cc.Intel;
        ct.JazzCash = cc.JazzCash;
        ct.Contact = cc.Contact;
        ct.No_Business = cc.No_Business;
        dbs.CustomerInfoes.Add(ct);
        dbs.SaveChanges();
        int CustomerID = ct.CustomerID;
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Model Code:

```
namespace Customer_Counter.Models
{
    public class CustomerCount
    {
        [Key]
        public int CustomerID { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Mobile { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Comments { get; set; }
        public Boolean Western_Union { get; set; }
        public Boolean Ria { get; set; }
        public Boolean Money_Gram { get; set; }
        public Boolean Intel { get; set; }
        public Boolean JazzCash { get; set; }
        public Boolean Contact { get; set; }
        public Boolean No_Business { get; set; }
    }
}
```

CustomerInfo:

```
namespace Customer_Counter.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class CustomerInfo
    {
        public int CustomerID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Mobile { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Comments { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Western_Union { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Ria { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Money_Gram { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Intel { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> JazzCash { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Contact { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> No_Business { get; set; }
    }
}
```

CustomerForm View: //Only the error part

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(Model => Model.Western_Union)
@Html.CheckBoxFor(Model => Model.Ria)//error
@Html.CheckBoxFor(Model => Model.Money_Gram)//error
@Html.CheckBoxFor(Model => Model.Intel)//error
@Html.CheckBoxFor(Model => Model.JazzCash)//error
@Html.CheckBoxFor(Model => Model.Contact)//error
@Html.CheckBoxFor(Model => Model.No_Business)//error
```

Comment: Can you add the first line of your view? Something like `@model CustomerSomething`

Answer (score 1):

You have this in your `CustomerCount` class (=SQL table?):

```
public Boolean Western_Union { get; set; }
public Boolean Ria { get; set; }
public Boolean Money_Gram { get; set; }
public Boolean Intel { get; set; }
public Boolean JazzCash { get; set; }
public Boolean Contact { get; set; }
public Boolean No_Business { get; set; }
```

but this in your `CustomerInfo` class (=model?):

```
public Nullable<bool> Western_Union { get; set; }
public Nullable<bool> Ria { get; set; }
public Nullable<bool> Money_Gram { get; set; }
public Nullable<bool> Intel { get; set; }
public Nullable<bool> JazzCash { get; set; }
public Nullable<bool> Contact { get; set; }
public Nullable<bool> No_Business { get; set; }
```

So either remove all those `Nullable`, or convert the value:

```
// Explicit conversion as suggested by your error message:
ct.Western_Union = (bool)cc.Western_Union;
// Function getting the boolean value or false if null:
ct.Western_Union = cc.Western_Union.GetValueOrDefault();
```

You could also get rid of your `CustomerInfo` class and *use* `CustomerCount` as your model.

---

**Edit:** [Hiba T](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56793635/7831383) solved your problem ([CheckBoxFor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.checkboxfor?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) has this overload:

```
CheckBoxFor<TModel>(HtmlHelper<TModel>, Expression<Func<TModel,Boolean>>)
```

note `Boolean`, not `Nullable<Boolean>`), but you really still should ask yourself why you use two (almost identical) classes for the same stuff.

Comment: I am using entity framework to update the table from the database

Comment: And so, what does it change?

Comment: In my razor view I have replaced CheckBoxFor with HtmlEditorFor and now everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

A "?" indicates a nullable type. A bool variable can be true or false. A nullable bool variable can be true, false or null. So mapping from a nullable bool to a non-nullable bool can not be done implicitly.

But to be honest, I think you need to do some reading on c#, MVC and sql in general ... your approach is a bit confusing, at least to me.

Answer (score 0):

ur varible should be true or false (not nullable), check ur database 
and this link might help u : [CheckBoxFor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16435476/9347361)