# Razor checkbox from list always false

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

In my class i have more attributes and all have the good value when i check after submit the form 
All variables are fine except the bool who is always false.
Can someone help me?
My class:

```
public class Pilot
{
    .....
    public bool OwnerOrPart { get; set; }
    .....
}
```

My model:

```
public class IardModel : RepositoryCollection
{
    .......
    public List<Pilot> Pilot { get; set; }
    .....
    public IardModel()
    {
        .....
        Pilot = new List<Pilot>();
        .....
    }
}
```

Controller:

    `public ActionResult Aeronef(IardModel model, string id) 
    { 
        if (id != "") { 
            using (var scope = RepositoryContainer.Container.BeginLifetimeScope()) 
            {
                var repository = scope.Resolve(); 
                model = repository.SingleById(id); 
                model.IsEditing = true; 
                return View(model); 
            } 
        }
        model.IsEditing = false; 
        return View(model); 
    }`

And the view:

```
@if (Model.Pilot.Count == 0)
{
    ....
    <section class="col col-md-2">
        <label class="label-form">(Co)Propriétaire</label>
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input name="Pilot[0].OwnerOrPart" type="checkbox" class="form-control">
            <i></i>
        </label>
    </section>
}
@foreach (var pilots in Model.Pilot)
{
    ....
    <section class="col col-md-2">
        <label class="label-form">(Co)Propriétaire</label>
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input name="Pilot[@(Model.Pilot.IndexOf(pilots))].OwnerOrPart" type="checkbox" class="form-control" @(pilots.OwnerOrPart ? "checked='checked'" : "")>
             <i></i>
         </label>
    </section>
}
```

All variables are fine except the bool who is always false.
Can someone help me

Comment: My controller:
 `public ActionResult Aeronef(IardModel model, string id)
        {

          
            if (id != "")
            {

                using (var scope = RepositoryContainer.Container.BeginLifetimeScope())
                {
                    var repository = scope.Resolve<IRepository>();
                    model = repository.SingleById<IardModel>(id);

                    model.IsEditing = true;
                    return View(model);
                }
            }

           
            model.IsEditing = false;
            return View(model);
        }`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Pilot[0].OwnerOrPart, new {@class = "form-control"})` instead of `<input type="checkbox" />`

**Edit**

I have write the code corresponding to this,

```
@if (Model.Pilot.Count == 0)
{
    ....
    <section class="col col-md-2">
        <label class="label-form">(Co)Propriétaire</label>
        <label class="checkbox">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Pilot[0].OwnerOrPart, new {@class = "form-control"})
            <i></i>
        </label>
    </section>
}
```

You can simply write this as,

```
@for(int i=0; i < Model.Pilot.Count; i++){
    ....
    <section class="col col-md-2">
        <label class="label-form">(Co)Propriétaire</label>
        <label class="checkbox">
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Pilot[i].OwnerOrPart, new {@class = "form-control"})
        <i></i>
        </label>
    </section>
}
```

Comment: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

Comment: @florea_g, Sorry, I just write the code that you have provided.

Comment: @florea_g, Please take a look at the updated answer.

Comment: @florea_g, Sorry for the question. Yes I got it from your question.

Comment: @florea_g, I have tested it with a test data in my machine. It is working fine. Could you please check your data?

Comment: i don't know where is the problem i paste this : `<section class="col col-md-2">
                                        <label class="label-form">(Co)Propriétaire</label>
                                        <label class="checkbox">
                                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Pilot[0].OwnerOrPart, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                            <i></i>
                                        </label>
                                    </section>`
and i get the error
You have used a list like me?

Comment: @florea_g, yes, I have also used a `List`. Did you debug your problem? Please add a watch to your list `Pilot` and `Model.Pilot[0].OwnerOrPart` to see what are the values.

Comment: I am quite a beginer in c#. Add a watch is the breakpoint? If so is always false.

Comment: I gived up now i use a select which is working very well.
`<section class="col col-md-2">
<label class="label-form">(Co)Propriétaire</label>
 <label class="select">
<select name="Pilot[0].OwnerOrPartTxt">
 <option value="Non">Non</option>
  <option value="Oui">Oui</option>
</select>
<i></i>
</label>
</section>`

Comment: @florea_g, For time being you can use this `select`. But don't give up, try to solve your problem when you get time.

Answer (score 0):

You should better use: `<input ... @(pilots.OwnerOrPart ? "checked='true'" : "")>`

See this

[How do I set a checkbox in razor view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157293/how-do-i-set-a-checkbox-in-razor-view)

and this

[Proper usage of .net MVC Html.CheckBoxFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12674572/proper-usage-of-net-mvc-html-checkboxfor)

Comment: The foreach is for edit the view so my problem is in if. My value in not binded is allways false. Maybe my checked is wrong but it will never work because my value isn't good